# Exact Partial Sum of Harmonic Series

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

#### Challenge

Given a positive integer `N`, output the sum of the first `N` reciprocals as an exact fraction, which is represented as a pair of integers in a consistent order representing numerator and denominator.

#### Rules

- Output must be exact.
- Output should be as a pair of integers in a consistent order representing numerator and denominator.
- Using non-integer numeric types (built-in or library) is forbidden.

  - Clarification/exception: non-integer numeric types are okay if and only if all values used, computed, and returned are integers (i.e. your language uses rational numbers by default, but you only use integer arithmetic in your answer)
- Output should be as reduced as possible. (`3/2` is okay, `6/4` is not)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Submissions should work for inputs at least up to 20, or [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8643/44694), whichever is higher.

#### Test Cases

```
1: 1/1
2: 3/2 (1/1 + 1/2)
3: 11/6 (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3)
4: 25/12 etc.
5: 137/60
6: 49/20
20: 55835135/15519504
56: 252476961434436524654789/54749786241679275146400
226: 31741146384418617995319820836410246588253008380307063166243468230254437801429301078323028997161/5290225078451893176693594241665890914638817631063334447389979640757204083936351078274058192000
```

#### [Test-Case Generation (Python 3)](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETPzVcshUKCodpWPRR69SfEQzCJ7iGbskmhfn1tRTqnecODGT/5HalbFgxj5AyezTNjpCSs8@DlrHoBa9jliQnSFOSu1Ld/k41GBT4yICABG3q5dZsPjVJLdiknGODe6FZ3@qwv@qrb00Ps/s/oRWEGL1GJYmSkLMvK9lDZY2VLqECiBlPTFBybHHkD6ygGpA3Xmy8)

```
import fractions
def f(x):
    return sum(fractions.Fraction(1,i) for i in range(1,x+1))
```

Similar to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123173/partial-sum-of-harmonic-sequence) and [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82815/denominator-of-harmonic-series).

Numerators are [OEIS A001008](http://oeis.org/A001008), and denominators are [OEIS A002805](http://oeis.org/A002805).

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16633/44694) (deleted)

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82815/48934)

Comment: Is `gcd` a "built-in function" if your language provides it?

Comment: @ChasBrown `gcd` and other built-in functions are fine. Rational/fractional types are not allowed.

Comment: support range?.

Comment: Can the returned pair of integers be fractional types? My Perl 6 answer only deals with integers, but the default type for numbers is Rat (a fractional type)

Comment: @JoKing That's fine if the numbers are rational type as long as only integers are used. I'll update the question.

Comment: @user202729 for the range: at least 20, and [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8643/44694)

Comment: @user202729 numerical errors are not allowed (i.e. the first input value that gives incorrect output values is considered to be outside your answer 's range)

Comment: Is the output for 20 shown here wrong? I get 55835135 and assumed my output was wrong, until I saw the top python answer also returns the same thing.

Comment: @sundar Fixed (it is 55835135, not 55835125)

Comment: Yes, that's the value I mentioned in my comment, but you've edited in the wrong value again in the question. Now the numerator says `55825135`, while it should say `55835135` (two 3's, no 2's).

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
!:RS,!:g/$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/RKihYR9EqXV/l/@H2R01r3P//N9RRMNJRMNZRMNFRMNVRMANyDYAsEG1kBgA)

#### How it works

```
!:RS,!:g/$  Main link. Argument: n

!           Compute n!.
  R         Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 :          Divide n! by each k in [1, ..., n].
   S        Take the sum. Let's call it s.
     !      Compute n! again.
    ,       Pair; yield [s, n!].
      :g/$  Divide [s, n!] by their GCD.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```python
D=1;N=n=0;exec"n+=1;y=N=N*n+D;x=D=D*n;"*input()
while y:x,y=y,x%y
print N/x,D/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCoMwFETX/acIQrFVQY3VheHvYpfpGVr7QWmJIaQ0OX0aoZuBYR5vTHDLpnmctydhnudRYisUamwEeZozXaYeUKEqdCmFR4my0CIrVm0@7nSG77K@iYXRVwFD5Y8BjF21Y6r2lax9TM4/047AnA0jHHYz2x@BkZ/JODbdrpO1m03jw9L9BbEFDh1coIcBeAN9Sj78AA)

Prints the numerator and denominator.

Yay! MathJax support!!!! One observes:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{n!i} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{i}}{n!}$$

Then, thinking about recursion, for \$n\$ positive, in the `N`umerator:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{(n+1)!}{i} = (n+1) \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{i} + \frac{(n+1)!}{n+1} = (n+1) \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{i} + n!$$

and one can't help think of the `D`enominator \$n!\$ recursively as well; thus the `exec`.

We must pay the Reduced Fraction Piper with a GCD calculation in the `while` loop; and then we're done.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
!(,%+.)1#.!%1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfpmBrpZCXX5qnkJKalpmX@l9RQ0dVW0/TUFlPUdVQO1PvvyZEDbo4V5qCWQWQMDIAkaZmFQA)

#### Run examples

```
f =: !(,%+.)1#.!%1+i.
f 6x
   20 49
f 20x
   15519504 55835135
f 56x
   54749786241679275146400 252476961434436524654789
```

#### How it works

```
!(,%+.)1#.!%1+i.    NB. Tacit verb
            1+i.    NB. 1 to n inclusive
          !%        NB. Divide factorial by 1 to n
       1#.          NB. Sum i.e. numerator (not reduced)
!                   NB. Factorial i.e. denominator (not reduced)
 (,%+.)             NB. Divide both by GCD
```

---

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes, using fraction type

```
1#.1%1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfpmBrpZCXX5qnkJKalpmX@t9QWc9Q1VA7U@@/JkQSLsCVpmBWASSMDECkqVkFAA)

J gives fractions for int-int division if not divisible.

Comment: [Only if one of the parameters are bigint](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19Bw1TVWJMLyqxAYqsaV2j@/w8A).

Comment: [You can use wrapper like this](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/xU1dFS19TQNlfUUVQ21M/X@a/5PUzCr4EpTMDIAkaZmFQA)

Comment: Would `2 x:1#.1%1+i.` count as a valid answer, or is this an invalid use of a rational type?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
!DIL÷O)D¿÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f0cXT5/B2f02XQ/sPb///38gAAA)

Uses the same method as all other entries. Output is in the form `[denominator, numerator]`.

```
!DIL÷O)D¿÷   Full program. Let's call the input I.
!D           Push the factorial twice to the stack. STACK: [I!, I!]
  IL         Range from 1 to I. STACK: [I!, I!, [1 ... I]]
    ÷        Vectorized integer division. STACK: [I!, [I! / 1, I! / 2, ..., I! / I]]
     O       Sum. STACK: [I!, I! / 1 + I! / 2 + ... + I! / I]
      )      Wrap stack. STACK: [[I!, I! / 1 + I! / 2 + ... + I! / I]]
       D     Duplicate. STACK: [[I!, I! / 1 + ... + I! / I], [I!, I! / 1 +... + I! / I]]
        ¿    GCD. STACK: [[I!, I! / 1 + ... + I! / I], gcd(I!, I! / 1 +... + I! / I)]
         ÷   Vectorized integer division.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
#/GCD@@#&@{Tr[#!/Range@#],#!}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19Z393ZxcFBWc2hOqQoWllRPygxLz3VQTlWR1mxVu2/S350QFFmXkl0noKunUJadF5srI5CdZ6OgoGOgrFBbex/AA)

---

### 14 bytes if built-in fractional types are allowed

```
HarmonicNumber
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98jsSg3Py8z2a80Nym16L9LfnRAUWZeSXSegq6dQlp0XmysjkJ1no6CgY6CsUFt7H8A)

Comment: `InputForm@HarmonicNumber` (24 bytes) gives output in the format given by OP.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```perl6
{+($!=[*] 1..$_)/($!=($/=sum $! X/1..$_)gcd$!),$//$!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pbQ0XRNlorVsFQT08lXlMfxNVQ0bctLs1VUFFUiNCHiKcnp6goauqo6OurKNb@T8svAqk3NFCo5lJQ0FNL0ytOrOSq/Q8A)

An anonymous code block that takes an integer and returns a tuple of `denominator, numerator`.

If we were allowed to use fractional types, it would be the much simpler 32 byter:

```perl6
{sum(map 1/*.FatRat,1..$_).nude}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q4NFcjN7FAwVBfS88tsSQosUTHUE9PJV5TL680JbX2f1p@kQJQwNBAoZpLQUFPLU2vOLGSq/Y/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

Returns `[numerator, denominator]`.

```javascript
f=(n,a=0,b=1)=>n?f(n-1,p=a*n+b,q=b*n):b?f(0,b,a%b):[p/a,q/a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY07DoMwEAV7TrFNhBfbfFICSw4SpVgTiEBobSBKE@Xsjpun0Wikt/KHz/FYwtuKf04xzqTEMNXGUYM0yG1WYhsTiAvRzuzkCsHWJZ0SwxeH7T1UbPaKH3H2hxIgaDoQ6AmudQKtEb4ZwOjl9NtUbv6VIg05WDuk1ZAusFz9IiqHCnLELvvFPw)

#### How?

The method is similar to [@ChasBrown's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168705/58563).

We first compute the unreduced numerator \$a\$ and unreduced denominator \$b\$ by starting with \$a=0\$ and \$b=1\$ and recursively doing:

$$a\gets an+b\\
b\gets bn\\
n\gets n-1$$

until \$n=0\$.

We save \$(a,b)\$ into \$(p,q)\$ and then compute \$a\gets \gcd(a,b)\$ with:

$$a\gets b\\
b\gets a \bmod b$$

until \$b=0\$.

We finally return the reduced numerator \$p/a\$ and reduced denominator \$q/a\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
n->l=[sum(i=1,n,n!/i),n!];l/gcd(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxCoAwDEDRq0SnBFqqOEq9iDiI0hKosVQ9f8zw3/Dr3tjnqgmiil9KXJ/vQo6jEyddYDK3uYR8nFhI091QIMLgYLJqY3lt9OAXI6EQkf4)

---

### 17 bytes if built-in fractional types are allowed

```
n->sum(i=1,n,1/i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/Xrrg0VyPT1lAnT8dQP1Pzf1p@kUaegq2CgY6CMRAXFGXmlQAFlBR07YBEmkaepqbmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 29 bytes

```matlab
@(n)sym(sprintf('+1/%i',1:n))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Nce9CoAgFAbQvaf4lvBeCkv7GYKg94iGqASHLFKCnt5aWg6cYwnzvUXTSynjQI79s5M/L@uCIZGpIrUiV51jjua4ENBjVNCoUKNBC12i@dTtlACr9ScZCsx/BAQnm1vjCw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C++17 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 108 bytes

Only use integer arithmetic:

```cpp
#import<random>
int f(int x,long&n,long&d){n=0;d=1;int
a;while(n=n*x+d,d*=x,a=std::gcd(n,d),n/=a,d/=a,--x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BasMwEETP8VcYCrEVySTppRCt8iW9CK3sCKyVsWVqCP71uJJT6GV2mdnljRmGpjNm2z6cH8IYYdSEwd8LR7Fs66yL6AN1R3oPZE9SF4nqKlNYaPnzcL2tSdFp4SjwpBah1RTxdusM1iSQCTorLTBL0yxMrglGpp/RggtTHK3@43ntqGbP4tCGcUe7TAH1eZGcuxwccoeSZm8FWgpeJiu1FP8Oy9aON2GOADkBqMoKYM/T/k1VOlqLdXuZttfdtDXpQRnOr1@/)

---

## [C++17 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 108 bytes

```cpp
#import<random>
int f(long&n){double a=0;long
d=1;while(d*=n,a+=1./n,--n);n=a*d+.5;n/=a=std::gcd(n,d);d/=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwEETP8VcYCrUU2UlcKIVI2y/pRdXKrkBeGVmmh@BfryuFEnp9M8MbM8/daMy@P7lpDjGpqAnD9F45SvXAfKDxmfgNw/rpba3hIguqEHr5/eW8ZXgEarWA/nSmtuuISwJ9RHF6lXQGDUvC63U0yKhFLjEjuWUZGb@iVS4sKVr955u0I8Zv1WEIkRXgssYpeLlIIVwJDsVe0zrZqFOI4GRmpYmWwuToDgf2KPCS3y@YsCalHoFSTd0o9W@WyQc1ub9V2/5jBq/HZe/yFowQ/dsv)

Same as below, but use C++17's [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).

---

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 109 bytes

```cpp
#import<regex>
int f(long&n){double a=0;long
d=1;while(d*=n,a+=1./n,--n);n=a*d+.5;n/=a=std::__gcd(n,d);d/=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7disIwEEav7VMUBJvY1p@FvTHJPsmCxExaB5pJiSkuSJ@9Ji6It@d8wxkzjm1vzLKs0Y0@RBlsb/9@CqRYdmzw1G@IP8BPl8GWWh1ERgWoo7hfcbAMtooaXavjbk9N2xIXpPQW6t23oL3S6hbhdDqfewOMGuACEhRzqpEZJrAS/S0Gq91/0Wkkxh/FqvOBZYAphFJ9HURdYxar3C9pcjbo6INCkVhegiXvkF6wY@8Bz/71hPFTlPItpKzKSsqPs0R@qUr7uZiXJw)

Because C++ doesn't have native bigint support, this will definitely overflow for `n>20`.

Require:

- gcc's deprecated `import` statement.
- gcc's `std::__gcd`.
- `-O0` (I think so) otherwise the compiler will optimize out `d/=a`.
- At least 64-bit `long`.

Explanation:

- Let \$d=n!, a=H_n\$.
- Round `a*d` to nearest integer by casting `a*d+.5` to `long`, and assign to `n`. Now `n/d` is the output.
- Simplify the fraction with `std::__gcd`.

Comment: Can't you use `auto a=0.` instead of `double a=0` (1 char less)?

Comment: Yes he can. And one more byte from the loop: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tc7RSsQwEAXQ5@1XFASbbjbdrSDCJvE3fPFlyKQ10E5CmiKy9NetaZXF13PvcMeEIHpj1vXBjcHHpCIQ@vG1cJTKjg2e@keqbzAnX4JuLnKTEjXJzw83WAZct82ZTkJQjcfMpOGIvHmWdNagp4TXa2@Q0QlriZnkkqfIDDNa5fyUooW/tREcsfpWHDof2QZOt9Ip/XSRnLstOOzjNI82QvJRO5lta6IlPzrasWP3Qr3l@wvGz0mpe6BUVVZK/TvL8k5V7i/Fsn6bboB@WkW@1Ybz9mUVb@RFtGmOJNJXsL@ANkRrIFn8AQ "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 13 bytes

```
:tptb/sht&Zd/
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%3Atptb%2Fsht%26Zd%2F&inputs=6&version=20.9.1)

Same method as used in [@Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168708/8774).

```
:t    % Range from 1 to n, duplicate. 
pt    % Take the product of that (= factorial), duplicate that too.     
b/    % Bring the range to top of stack, divide factorial by each element    
sh    % Sum those. Concatenate factorial and this into a single array.     
t&Zd/ % Compute GCD of those and divide the concatenated array elements by the GCD.
```

(Implicit output, prints denominator first and then the numerator.)

<s>Floating point inaccuracies mean this doesn't work for n = 20, because the intermediate values are too large.</s> Looks like the test case output was a typo, this returns the same answer as the other answers for n=20.

Here's an integer type-preserving version (25 bytes) I tried in the meantime, before finding this out:

#### 25 bytes, input upto 43

```
O1i:3Y%"t@*b@*b+wht&Zd/Z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/398w08o4UlWpxEErCYi0jVRKolL0y0199f/HZqirpuirpqhHuvw3MQYA)

Casts the numbers to `uint64` before operating on them, does the arithmetic explicitly in a loop (without using `prod` or `sum`). More importantly, divides the partial numerators and denominators by their GCD every step along the way, at the end of each iteration. This increases the input range to allow `n` upto 43. Part of the code is based on @Chas Brown's Python answer.

Alternate (original) method using LCM instead of factorial:

#### <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
:t&Zmtb/sht&Zd/
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%3At%26Zmtb%2Fsht%26Zd%2F&inputs=6&version=20.9.1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ó╢Δ'åç4}ú┌7
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a2b6ff278687347da3da37&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A20%0A56%0A226&a=1&m=2)

Explanation:

We want to calculate:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac 1 i}$$

We now need a denominator \$b\$ and a list of numerators \$a_i\$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{a_i}b}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}}{b}$$

We can make \$b=n!\$, then we have:

\begin{align}
  \frac{a_i}{n!}&=\frac 1 i&|\times n! \\
  a_i&=\frac{n!}i
\end{align}

So we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac 1 n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{n!}i}}{n!}$$

```
|Fx{[/m|+L:_m Full program
|F            Factorial
  x           Push input again
   {  m       Map over range [1, n]
    [           Copy the factorial
     /          Divide factorial by current value
       |+     Sum
         L    Listify stack, top gets first element
          :_  Divide both values by gcd
            m Print each followed by newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```apl
⌽!(,÷∨)1⊥!÷⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HPXkUNncPbH3Ws0DR81LVUEcjs3fw/7VHbhEe9fY/6pnr6P@pqPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/Tzu0AqjSyAAA)

Tacit function, taking a single argument `⍵`. Saves a byte by removing the `⌽` if we're allowed to print the denominator first.

Thanks @dzaima for 3 bytes.

#### How:

```apl
⌽!(,÷∨)1⊥!÷⍳ ⍝ Tacit function, argument will be called ⍵.
           ⍳ ⍝ Range 1..⍵ 
          ÷  ⍝ Dividing
         !   ⍝ the factorial of ⍵
       1⊥    ⍝ Base-1 decode, aka sum;
 !(   )      ⍝ Using that sum and the factorial of ⍵ as arguments, fork:
     ∨       ⍝ (GCD
    ÷        ⍝ dividing
   ,         ⍝ the vector with both arguments)
⌽            ⍝ reversed.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 141 bytes

Takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the console.

```vb
s="=If(Row()>A$1,":[B:B]=s+"1,Row())":l=[LCM(B:B)]:[C:C]=s &"0,"&l &"/B1)":g=[GCD(LCM(B:B),SUM(C:C))]:?Format([Sum(C:C)]/g,0)"/"Format(l/g,0)
```

#### Ungolfed and Commented

```vb
Sub HarmonicSum(n)
    [A1] = n                            ''  Pipe input
    s = "=IF(ROW()>A$1,"                ''  Hold the start of formulas
    [B1:B40] = s + "1,ROW())"           ''  Get series of numbers 1 to N, trailing 1s
    l = [LCM(B1:B40)]                   ''  Get LCM
    [C1:C40] = s & "0," & l & "/B1)"    ''  Get LCM/M for M in 1 to N
    g = [GCD(LCM(B1:B40),SUM(C1:C40))]  ''  Get GCD
                                        ''  Format and print output
    Debug.Print Format([Sum(C1:C40)] / g, 0); "\"; Format(l / g, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 87 bytes

```
?sn1dsNsD[lndlDdlNln*+sN*sD1-dsn1<M]sMln1<MlDsAlNsB[lAlB%sTlBsAlTsBlB0<G]dsGxlDlA/lNlA/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCoAwEARfY6OIibUgOQ5SJVW6YOVhtaTZxt/HWA3DwNjd@8nmjZla0QxqyGjzwjxT/WojHuliwk8oAzKlIkAmFsjwQoG4I17G@EIRtnEIW3/67j4)

This leaves the numerator and denominator on top of the stack in that order, as allowed by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8507/52405) output default. Since `dc` does not have a `gcd` built-in, this utilizes the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid's_algorithm) to calculate the `gcd`.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 56 chars, 112 bytes

```
{⍵=1:⊂1 1⋄{(r s)←⍺⋄(i j)←⍵⋄m÷∨/m←((r×j)+s×i),s×j}/1,¨⍳⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵=1:⊂1 1⋄{(r s)←⍺⋄(i j)←⍵⋄m÷∨/m←((r×j)+s×i),s×j}/1,¨⍳⍵}
  f 1
1 1 
  f 2
3 2 
  f 3
11 6 
  f 20
55835135 15519504
```

In few words reduce "sum function on 2 fraction numbers" (one fraction number is a list 2 integers) on the set:

```
1 2, 1 3,..., 1 n
```

this below seems wrong:

```
 f 56
74359641471727289 16124934538402170
```

but if i change the type of input than:

```
  f 56x
252476961434436524654789 54749786241679275146400 
  f 226x
31741146384418617995319820836410246588253008380307063166243468230254437801429301078323028997161 529022507845189
  3176693594241665890914638817631063334447389979640757204083936351078274058192000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 14 bytes

```
Đ!⇹ř/Đ↑⇹ƩáĐÁǤ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yATFR@07j87UPzLhUdtEIPPYysMLj0w43Hh8if7//4YGBgYA)

Outputs `[denominator, numerator]`.

```
Đ                 implicit input; Đuplicate
 !                factorial
  ⇹               swap top two on stack
   ř              řangify
    /             divide
     Đ↑           Đuplicate; get max
       ⇹          swap top two on stack
        Ʃ         Ʃum
         á        push stack to árray
          Đ       Đuplicate
           Á      push contents of Árray to stack
            Ǥ     get ǤCD
             /    divide; implicit print
```