# Exact Sum of 1/2 to 1/n

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Consider the sequence 1/2, 1/3 + 1/2, 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2, and so on. In mathematical symbols, this is

$$S(n)=\sum_{m=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{m}$$

where S is the function that makes the sequence.

Outputting this sequence as a fraction would not be complicated. To add depth to the challenge, you must output as a repeating decimal.

To represent non-repeating decimals, simply output the decimal. To represent repeating decimals, put an R before the repeating part.

For example, 1/7 can be represented by `0.R142857`, and 11/9 by `1.R2`

Your task is to output the nth number in this sequence, and because this is code-golf the shortest program will win.

Comment: I strongly feel that this is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/168700/78410 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89215/78410. OP contains a slight variation of both (sum formula is offset by one, and notation for repeating decimal is different), but both changes are minor compared to the core of the tasks.

Comment: Need it be simpliest?

Comment: @I4m2 The decimals do not need to be in simplest form.

Comment: @Bubbler I'm voting to close this as a duplicate; I think that's the best idea for this question.