# Most Common Multiple

Tags: code-golf, array

*Not to be confused with [Least Common Multiple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94999/least-common-multiple).*

Given a list of positive integers with more than one element, return the most common product of two elements in the array.

For example, the MCM of the list `[2,3,4,5,6]` is `12`, as a table of products is:

```
    2  3  4  5  6
  ---------------
2 | #  6  8  10 12
3 | #  #  12 15 18
4 | #  #  #  20 24
5 | #  #  #  #  30
6 | #  #  #  #  #
```

*Thanks DJMcMayhem for the table*

As `12` appears the most times (two times as `2*6` and `3*4`). Note that we aren't including the product of an element and itself, so `2*2` or `4*4` do not not appear in this list. However, identical elements will still be multiplied, so the table for `[2,3,3]` looks like:

```
    2  3  3
  ----------
2 | #  6  6 
3 | #  #  9
3 | #  #  #
```

With the MCM being `6`.

In the event of a tie, you may return any of the tied elements, or a list of all of them.

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest byte count for each language wins!

#### Test-cases:

```
[2,3,4,5,6] -> 12
[7,2] -> 14
[2,3,3] -> 6
[3,3,3] -> 9
[1,1,1,1,2,2] -> 2
[6,200,10,120] -> 1200
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8] -> 24
[5,2,9,10,3,4,4,4,7] -> 20
[9,7,10,9,7,8,5,10,1] -> 63, 70, 90 or [63,70,90]
```

Comment: [Sandbox (deleted)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16638/76162)

Comment: Is there test case where a whole N*N most isn't triangle most?

Answer (score 12):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
{⊇Ċ×}ᶠọtᵒth
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9icmFjaHlsb2cy//974oqHxIrDl33htqDhu4104bWSdGj//1syLDMsNCw1LDZd/1o)

#### Explanation

```
{   }ᶠ          Find all:
 ⊇Ċ×              Product of a subset of 2 elements
      ọtᵒ       Order by occurrences
         th     Take the last element and discard the number of occurrences
```

Comment: I don't know how code golf usually works but aren't some of these characters outside the standard 256 code points and therefore multiple bytes each?

Comment: @Holloway [Brachylog uses a custom code page](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page)

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>54</s> <s>50</s> 41 bytes

```r
order(-tabulate(combn(scan(),2,prod)))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P78oJbVIQ7ckMak0J7EkVSM5PzcpT6M4OTFPQ1PHSKegKD9FU1Mz2jD2v5GCsYKJgqmCmYK5goWCxX8A)

Alternatively, for <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 44 bytes:

```r
names(sort(-table(combn(scan(),2,prod))))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py8xN7VYozi/qERDtyQxKSdVIzk/NylPozg5MU9DU8dIp6AoP0UTCKINY/8bKRgrmCiYKpgpmCtYKFj8BwA)

In principle, the latter version outputs the relevant result even without the `names` function, but followed by the count of such most frequent products, which isn't asked for...

Thanks to CriminallyVulgar  for -4 and -1, and Giuseppe for -9 on both.

Comment: On the second on you can use -table() instead of descending=TRUE for -1. I really like the cleverness of the first one though. EDIT: Just realised you can also apply that to the first one for -4, so there's that. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P78oJbVIQ7ckMak0J7EkVSOxoCCnUiM5PzcpT6M4OTFPQ1PHCIh0CoryUzQ1NaMNY/8bKRgrmCiYKpgpmCtYKFj8BwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: `combn(scan(),2,prod)` works instead of using `apply`

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒcP€Æṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opOSAR01rDrc93Nn8////aCMdYx0THVMds1gA) or [Check out the test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opOSAR01rDrc93Nn8/3A7kOn@/3@0kY6xjomOqY5ZrI5CtLmOEYgCiRmDGIY6EGgEETfTMTIw0DEEIiMDmDqwXh1zHQsdC5CQKVCtJUgJSAYEzUGilkAFQDFLsDpTsAmxAA).

#### How it works

```
ŒcP€Æṃ – Full program / Monadic link.
Œc     – Unordered pairs without replacement.
  P€   – Product of each.
    Æṃ – Mode (most common element).

Alternative: ŒcZPÆṃ
```

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
eo/QN=*M.cQ2
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eo%2FQN%3D%2aM.cQ2&input=%5B2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B7%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%5D%0A%5B6%2C200%2C10%2C120%5D%0A%5B2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C8%5D%0A%5B5%2C2%2C9%2C10%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C7%5D%0A%5B9%2C7%2C10%2C9%2C7%2C8%2C5%2C10%2C1%5D&debug=0)

First, we take all 2 element combinations of the input without replacement (`.cQ2`). Then, we map each of these pairs to their product (`*M`). Next, we overwrite the input variable with the list of products (`=`). Next, we sort the list of products by the number of occurrences in the list of products (`o/QN`). Finally, the take the final element of the sorted list (`e`).

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
2XN!pXM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYu9CoAwDIR338L9hja1f7urTg6FUtBdwcH3j2mUCzm4@@46npN3prKOd1l43rgSHCZ4hDbUCJLfEyfufrf4RNoGkDGwcmR@WOeISEiSeAFzB3rRFSXMUkuUlfI6by8)

*(-1 byte by using the method from @Mr. Xcoder's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170052/8774).)*

```
2XN     % nchoosek - get all combinations of 2 elements from input
!p      % get the product of each combination
XM      % 'mode': get the most common value from that
```

---

Older answer:

#### 8 bytes

```
&*XRXzXM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYu9CoAwEIN3H8RBMrRX@7e7uohDoRR0183Jlz@vteS4QPLlPp@LDx6ntKU3rbzsnAkGMyxcGbIHya@JETfdNX5Rax1IKWg5Uh1uc3gEBEmsgLECtajyEkapJYqNsm1ePg)

```
&*    % multiply input by its transpose,
      %  getting all elementwise products
XR    % take the upper-triangular portion of that,
      %  zeroing out repetitions and mainly self-multiplications
Xz    % remove the zeroed out parts
XM    % 'mode' calculation - get the most common value from that
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

<sup>*-17 bytes (and a fix) thanks to [JungHwan Min](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60043).*</sup>

```
Commonest[1##&@@@#~Subsets~{2}]&
```

Pure function. Takes a list of numbers as input and returns the list of MCMs as output.

Comment: Actually it looks like both of us misread the question. This fails for input `{3, 3, 3}`. Fixed: `Commonest[1##&@@@#~Subsets~{2}]&`

Comment: @JungHwanMin Huh. I thought that `Subsets` didn't count repeats as separate elements. It seems like it does, though, so thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æ2ùP.M
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Kaldo*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8DKjwzsD9Hz//4820jHWMdEx1TGLBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/p5ulir6TwqG2SgpK9y//Dy4wO7wzQ8/2v8z/aSMdYx0THVMcslivaXMcISIJEjIG0oQ4EGoFFzXSMDAx0DIHIyACqCKxNx1zHQscCKGIKVGgJUgCSAEFzoKAlUBooZAlWZQrWDhQ1BtsAAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
æ         # Take the powerset of the input-list
          #  i.e. [2,3,3] → [[],[2],[3],[3],[2,3],[2,3],[3,3],[2,3,3]]
 2ù       # Leave only the inner lists of size 2:
          #  i.e. [[],[2],[3],[3],[2,3],[2,3],[3,3],[2,3,3]] → [[2,3],[2,3],[3,3]]
   P      # Take the product of each remaining pair
          #  i.e. [[2,3],[2,3],[3,3]] → [6,6,9]
    .M    # Only leave the most frequent value(s) in the list
          #  i.e. [6,6,9] → [6]
```

Comment: æ2ùP.M for 6 bytes

Comment: @Kaldo Thanks! Completely forgot about `ù`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```perl6
{key max bag(@_ X*@_)∖@_»²: *{*}:}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzo7tVIhN7FCISkxXcMhXiFCyyFe81HHNIf4Q7sPbbJS0KrWqrWq/V@cWKmQplGjEq@pkJZfxBVtpGOsY6JjqmMWq8MVba5jBKJAYsYghqEOBBpBxM10jAwMdAyByMgApg6sV8dcx0LHAiRkClRrCVICkgFBc5CoJVABUMwSrM4UbEKs9X8A)

Comment: Could you please explain to me (or point me to the docs) what are the colons doing there? I can't quite make it out... I can see that it has something to do with argument passing but nothing more.

Comment: @Ramillies That's the [infix `:`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_%3A) operator.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, 43 bytes

```
I=input('');i=I'*I*1-eye(nnz(I));mode(i(:))
```

It's also kind of a tongue twister!

**Explanation**

```
I=input('');           % Takes an input like "[2,3,4,5,6]"
i=I'*I                 % Multiplies the input by its own transverse
      *1-eye(nnz(I));  % Multiplies by 1-identity matrix to remove diagonal
mode(i(:))             % Calculates most common value and prints it
```

Comment: i am not sure you need to do `I'*I*1-eye` Why not just `I'*I-eye`?

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╢êv^⌐ö►♣Ä»
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b688765ea99410058eaf&i=[2,3,4,5,6]%0A[7,+2]%0A[2,3,3]%0A[1,1,1,1,2,2]%0A[6,200,10,120]%0A[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8]%0A[5,2,9,10,3,4,4,4,7]%0A[9,7,10,9,7,8,5,10,1]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(m=o=(y,Y)=>a.map(x=>Y--<0?m=(o[x*=y]=-~o[x])<m?m:o[r=x]:0))|r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BbsIwDIbvfYocE@SCm9KWIAzPgSofIgbTJkJQmaYiTbx6l8JApWVxDnH05cvvT/ttT5vq4/gVH/zbttlRY2lpx84epSNP8gxrdb@oabmO4wWuHElf1iM6M8WXcGK1cCs392VFNc9RqZ@q2fjDye@3471/lztZakhhChnkLB5LKTGZiERHPbYA3aGe2Gn0wpvyKzbvowncSnf0N3SQIAeNCEnYGrmXFjH6bzYoYAYz7ogHebPwvWnN7ZO2Cr6zA68JvkCaqza7xuG/2VIQBYIwKHwlytCGziA3vw)

Comment: @tsh The problem is the main diagonal, where multiples should not be counted at all. So it fails for the penultimate test case which has three \$16\$ on the main diagonal, bringing its score high enough to be returned instead of the expected \$20\$.

Comment: Do you need the `<0`? Top half = Top half + Bottom half

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>77</s> 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,*l,m=[]:l and f(*l,m=m+[k*x for x in l])or max(m,key=m.count)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzbDoMgDEDf/Yo@omsWxXlN/BJCFjZ1MwIao4t@vStslLTl9JT5WN@TTc@zb7Qyj1bBiJFG0whZa1C2hZ75t7mIMdqhnxbYYbCgZUitUTszOHZHY67PabNreDrj7oxF2VfHyrAOAOZlsCujr7qP0myw87aykM4pOKZ4wwxzGYgCOWVHUqoJ/oJ7miOPY0zo8vgv@TUssMSSSEZi5QQ3cFEQrGhMqPJW5tflFw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 59 bytes

```
Last##~SortBy#`&&:`~##{Flat[UpperTriangle&1!Table&_!`*]^^0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU1NC4JAEL37KyY2PMQcTDNT6FLQKSLITsuWm60WRIm7l4j667a1buTwhvl6bx5Xiucn0RSQTJsll4qQ1@ZWq9mdZK6bZC9CHosLV3RbVaJO6zO/lhfhDnspP@i672UDttt5z2YlxFHSflXlJXPW9fmqUiHVnEshaYFAHdBBfYQAYYQQIowZmmWE4NveEAI7Bt1xiPCD/6ca697z9PqTvtd91rohaJ@Jhr2G3x@xURmeQWQZ8VfzOcdWHbYmzGGseQM)

Still working on golfing this down a bit, but I think this is near optimal for the approach I've chosen.

### Explanation

This is a composition of three functions:

1. `` {Flat[UpperTriangle&1!Table&_!`*]^^0} ``
2. `` SortBy#`&&:`~ ``
3. `Last`

The first function does the bulk of the computation:

```
{Flat[UpperTriangle&1!Table&_!`*]^^0}
{                                   }    anonymous lambda; input: _ (e.g.: [2,3,4,5,6])
                      Table&_!`*         shorthand for Table[`*, _]
                                         this creates a multiplication table using the input
                                         e.g.:
                                           4  6  8 10 12
                                           6  9 12 15 18
                                           8 12 16 20 24
                                          10 15 20 25 30
                                          12 18 24 30 36

      UpperTriangle&1!                   takes the strict upper triangle of this matrix
                                         e.g.:
                                          0 6  8 10 12
                                          0 0 12 15 18
                                          0 0  0 20 24
                                          0 0  0  0 30
                                          0 0  0  0  0
Flat[                           ]^^0     flattens this list and removes all 0s
                                         e.g.: [6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18, 20, 24, 30]
```

The second is a bit complicated but does something rather simple. First, it is useful to know that `f&n` is a function which, when called with arguments `...x`, returns `f[...x, n]`. `f&:n` is similar, returning `f[n, ...x]`. Now, let's decompose this:

```
( ~SortBy ) # (`& &: `~)
```

First, `f#g` creates a fork. With input `n`, it returns `f[n, g[n]]`. However, in this case, `f` is the function `~SortBy`. `~f` reverses the arguments of the function. This means that `~f#g` is equivalent to `f[g[n], n]`, or here, `` SortBy[(`& &: `~)[n], n] ``.

`` `& &: `~ `` follows the form `f&:n`. But what are `` `& `` and `` `~ ``? They are "operator quotes", and return a function equivalent to the quoted operator. So, in this case, `` `& `` is the same thing as `${ x & y }`. With that in mind, this expression is equivalent to the following for binary operators:

```
f&:n   <=>   ${ f[n, x] }
       <=>   ${ (`&)[`~, x] }
       <=>   ${ `~ & x }
```

This yields the function `` `~&x ``, where `x` is the result from the first function. `n ~ a` counts the occurrences of `n` in `a`. So, this returns a function which counts the occurrences of the argument in the computed array from function 1.

Going back to `SortBy`, this each element in the array by the number of times it appears in it.

Finally, `Last` takes the element which occurs the most. Ties are broken by the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Is the UpperTriangle part required? Can you just flatten the table and sort?

Comment: @svavil Yes, it is required; `[5, 2, 9, 10, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7] -> 16` instead of `20` without it.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>29 27</s> 19 bytes

```apl
{⌈/⊢/⊣¨⌸∊⍵}⍳∘≢↓¨⊢×⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRT4f@o65FQLz40IpHPTsedXQ96t1a@6h386OOGY86Fz1qmwwU71p0ePqjrqb/aY/aJjzq7XvUN9XT/1FX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4/6PeVWmHVmhYKpgrGBoogCgLBVMQ01BTQcNIwVjBBMg1A7LNFYygIsZA2hhKGypAoBFY1kzByMAArNnIAFk72FQLoIgpUKElSAFIAgTNNQE)

Tacit fn.

Thanks to Adám for the tacit version and 2 bytes.

Thanks to ngn for 8 bytes!

#### How:

```apl
{⌈/⊢/⊣¨⌸∊⍵}⍳∘≢↓¨⊢×⊂
                ⊢×⊂   ⍝ Multiply each element with the entire argument, then
           ⍳∘≢↓¨      ⍝ Remove 1 from the first, two from the next etc. (removes repeated multiplications);
                      ⍝ The result is then fed into the function:
{       ∊⍵}           ⍝ Flatten the result;
     ⊣¨⌸              ⍝ Key; creates a matrix in which each row corresponds to a unique product;
   ⊢/                 ⍝ Get the rightmost column of the matrix;
 ⌈/                   ⍝ Get the highest value.
```

Comment: This is only [27](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X8NQwehRV/Oj3kmPerYfWvGoq0lTQ@dR74pHHTMedS561LMDxOjoetS7GSrSNhmkatHh6SCl/9MetU141Nv3qG@qpz/QmEPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/0e9q9IOrdCwVDBXMDRQAFEWCqYgpqGmgoaRgrGCCZBrBmSbKxhBRYyBtDGUNlSAQCOwrJmCkYEBWLORAbJ2sKkWQBFToEJLkAKQBAiaawIA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
2ċ€pṀ
```

##### Explanation

```python
2ċ€pṀ  # Implicit input
2ċ     # Combinations of length 2 of the input
  €p   # Product of each pair in this list
    Ṁ  # Mode of this list
       # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＷθＦ×⊟θθ⊞υκＩ⊟Φυ⁼№υι⌈Ｅυ№υλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYs9C8IwEIZ3f0XGC5xgB1HpWHQrZHArHY4SSTAxzZf672Oi4Lvc3fPcuygKiyNTyktpIxl4zm4uMLhqKyMIt1aCzHPORI4KMrI77zci6EeCgWL6vly0STI0efaZTITB5errrWt5pLe22cJIa0N/Z/gvfSnTdMIDdjts44j7tnbzXLZP8wE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗθ
```

While the input array is non-empty...

```
×⊟θθ
```

... pop the last element and multiply the rest of the array by that element...

```
Ｆ...⊞υκ
```

... and push the results to the predefined empty list.

```
⌈Ｅυ№υλ
```

Count the number of times each product appears in the list and take the maximum...

```
Φυ⁼№υι...
```

... then filter for the products whose count equals that maximum...

```
Ｉ⊟
```

...then pop the last element and cast to string for implicit print.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>20</s> 16 bytes

- -4 bytes from @Shaggy

---

```
£s°Y m*XÃc
ñ@è¥X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9Di4kMbIhVytSIONydzHd7ocHjFoaUR//9HW@qY6xga6IAoCx1TENMwVkE3AwA)

Comment: [16 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o3OwWSBtKljDYwrxQOilWA==&input=WzIsMyw0LDUsNl0KLWg=)

Comment: You can replace `£...Ãc` with `c@...` for -1 byte (not sure it existed at the time)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
Ṡ►#mΠṖ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fG5yvnaCtpKBrp6CkUfyoqbFI89C2/w93Lng0bZdy7rkFD3dOM/r//3@0kY6xjomOqY5ZLFe0uY4RkASJGANpYyhtqAOBRmBZMx0jAwMdQyAyMoAqBmvXMdex0LEAipgCFVqCFIAkQNAcKGgJlAYKWYJVmYK1xwIA)

### Explanation

```
Ṡ►#mΠṖ2  -- example input [3,3,3]
     Ṗ2  -- subsequences of length 2: [[3,3],[3,3],[3,3]]
   mΠ    -- map product: [9,9,9]
Ṡ        -- apply 
  #      -- | count occurences in list
 ►       -- to maxOn that list: [9]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```
q',/S*~_,(:L{LX-,0a\+[{X1++}*](;{_X=\_Y=@*\}fY}fX]~;]_{\_@e=}$\;_,(=
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%27%2C%2FS*~_%2C1-%3AL%7BLX-%2C0a%5C%2B%5B%7BX1%2B%2B%7D*%5D(%3B%7B_X%3D%5C_Y%3D%40*%5C%7DfY%7DfX%5D~%3B%5D_%7B%5C_%40e%3D%7D%24%5C%3B_%2C1-%3D&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D)

### Explanation

```
q',/S*~                                                                  Turn input string into a valid CJam array
       _,(                                                               Find the length of the array and subtract 1
          :L                                                             Assign the result to L
            {                                 }fX                        Outer for loop
             LX-,0a\+[{X1++}*](;                                         Create an array with all the array indexes bigger than X
                                {          }fY                           Inner for loop
                                 _X=\_Y=@*\                              Create a multiple of array[X] and array[Y] (Guaranteed to be from a unique combination of factors)
                                                 ~;]                     Casts away all stack items except for an array of the multiples
                                                    _{\_@e=}$\;          Sorts array by number of occurrences (largest number of occurences at the end)
                                                               _,(=      Gets the last element of the array
```

You will need to scroll right to see the explanations as the code is quite long, as well as the explanations.

---

This was an absolute nightmare to write. CJam doesn't have a powerset function (unlike a ton of other golfing languages - great choice on my part), which means that I had to manually find the powerset. However, this gave me the opportunity to ignore any invalid number of factors, unlike other answers with a powerset function.

This should be golfable, considering I'm terrible at CJam.

---

#### Changes:

[Helen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58707/helen) cut off 2 bytes!

Old: `q',/S*~_,1-:L{LX-,0a\+[{X1++}*](;{_X=\_Y=@*\}fY}fX]~;]_{\_@e=}$\;_,1-=`
New: `q',/S*~_,(:L{LX-,0a\+[{X1++}*](;{_X=\_Y=@*\}fY}fX]~;]_{\_@e=}$\;_,(=`

By changing the `1-`s to simply `(` we get the same effect but with a lower byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>7</sup></s> 6 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to The Thonnu*

```
2ḋvΠ∆M
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiMuG4i3bOoOKIhk0iLCIiLCJbMiwzLDQsNSw2XVxuWzcsMl1cblsyLDMsM11cblszLDMsM11cblsxLDEsMSwxLDIsMl1cbls2LDIwMCwxMCwxMjBdXG5bMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw4XVxuWzUsMiw5LDEwLDMsNCw0LDQsN11cbls5LDcsMTAsOSw3LDgsNSwxMCwxXSJd)

Comment: There's a command for "mode", so you can save one byte: [6 bytes, Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiMuG4i3bOoOKIhk0iLCIiLCJbMiwzLDQsNSw2XVxuWzcsMl1cblsyLDMsM11cblszLDMsM11cblsxLDEsMSwxLDIsMl1cbls2LDIwMCwxMCwxMjBdXG5bMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw4XVxuWzUsMiw5LDEwLDMsNCw0LDQsN11cbls5LDcsMTAsOSw3LDgsNSwxMCwxXSJd)

Comment: You can also use the Cartesian product for 5 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuop2zqDiiIZNIiwiIiwiWzIsMyw0LDUsNl0iXQ==)

Comment: Cartesian product [doesn't actually work](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwi4bqKds6g4oiGTSIsIiIsIlsyLDMsNCw1LDZdIC0+IDEyXG5bNywyXSAtPiAxNFxuWzIsMywzXSAtPiA2XG5bMywzLDNdIC0+IDlcblsxLDEsMSwxLDIsMl0gLT4gMlxuWzYsMjAwLDEwLDEyMF0gLT4gMTIwMFxuWzIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOF0gLT4gMjRcbls1LDIsOSwxMCwzLDQsNCw0LDddIC0+IDIwXG5bOSw3LDEwLDksNyw4LDUsMTAsMV0gLT4gNjMiXQ==) so you'll have to switch back to the 6-byter

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 132 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,i=l,j=0,r=99999,m[]=new int[r];for(;i-->0;)for(j=l;--j>i;)m[a[i]*a[j]]++;for(;r-->0;)i=m[r]<i?i:m[j=r];return j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFdb4IwFH33V9yYmMi8EMT5iXXxZcke9uTeCA@dgmsHhbTFxRh@u2vBjZlRSHvuuef2Hi6nJ@ryw@eV5WUhNXCDvUqzzHsIe/9iaSX2mhXCkmX1nrE97DOqFLxSJuDSA7hFlababKeCHSA33HCnJRPHKAYqj8ppUgHeihehn28110zoKN5ACuRK3c3FQMgI9bJEHPUHMpIhJz5KsrQP5lFMRPIFViXjMC3kMGSuu/FDx545yULX5RsWOnlEIxY/0IjH8WjUZso2k5HciNfsia3yiBNTRya6kgJ4WF/DpsemK9O3TpRWQG6dA1wCnOAjTnFW409ojkEHLD/p4OQejrFdwV/JDAPfx7F5A/@@UHMRznGBi46YGvXSplvernnHLU2yYZaNZtrUvJF168v@hsZb42zV@nN@7e3OSie5V1TaK83kdDrsD9QKBoeB6CNspaRn5emiHevQih2E1KNlmZ23yoy1jTntZXXPfvX1Gw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>96</s> 94 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi) (using `sortOn(0<$)` instead of `length`)!</sup>

```hs
import Data.List
f a|b<-zip[0..]a=last.last.sortOn(0<$).group$sort[x*y|(i,x)<-b,(j,y)<-b,i/=j]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LboMwELzzFauIg2kWl0AJoYJe2mOqHnqkqHJUkjjlYWFHJVX@ndoOjeK1VuOZ2ZF3z@R3VdfjyBvR9QpemGJ0zaVytsDOm8z/5aIIKC1ZXjOpqG1SO99aEmSuR3d9dxSuYYrh7nQmHAcv8zdIDniygN/nh3KsBtaIupKQOwAFFCFG@IAxLkv9RigSDCdklGjC0Q1e4KXCq3OJYRDgQt8wuBm2sZjgClcTG@uh1BiNaCqZhFTbNJ1ad2yjjFI6TsN4Czk0TLx@AvkYpP8E4qjeVb9uwQW5735gkDCfwwy0NDPIkmSrec/TKfpQII//m1@pvmJfF5xnGewq9dy1qmqVHPWO5gd/)

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB 39 bytes

```
a=input('');
b=triu(a'*a,1);
mode(b(b~=0))
```

Also check out [answer by Jacob Watson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170084/80759)

Comment: Having the second line be `b=triu(a'*a,1);` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: @sundar Oh snap, you are right :) I had `triu` intially but drifted away somehow

Comment: Good solution, I didn't realise the upper triangle function was so short!

Answer (score 2):

## SQL Server, 93 bytes

```
SELECT TOP 1a.a*b.a
FROM @ a
JOIN @ b ON a.i<b.i
GROUP BY a.a*b.a
ORDER BY COUNT(a.a*b.a)DESC
```

Input is assumed to come from a table of the form

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (A int, i int identity);
```

Example table population:

```
INSERT INTO @ VALUES (9), (7), (10), (9), (7), (8), (5), (10), (1);
```

Explanation:

I assume a "list of integers" will have an index associated with them, which in my case is the column `i`. The column `a` contains the values of the list.

I create products of every pair, where the left pair comes in the list earlier than the right pair. I then group on the product, and sort by the most populous number.

I'm a little sad I didn't get to use any cte or partitioning clauses, but they were just too long. `SELECT` is a very expensive keyword.

## Alternative, 183 bytes

```
WITH c
AS(SELECT a,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY a)r
FROM @),d AS(SELECT a.a*b.a p,COUNT(a.a*b.a)m
FROM c a
JOIN c b ON a.r<b.r GROUP BY a.a*b.a)SELECT TOP 1p
FROM d
ORDER BY m DESC
```

If SQL doesn't get to have a separate index column, here is a solution where I create an index using the `ROW_NUMBER` function. I personally don't care about the order, but an order is required and using the `a` column is the shortest.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 29 bytes

```
q~:L,2m*{:-},{Lf=:*}%$e`:e>1=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7DOykfHKFer2kq3VqfaJ83WSqtWVSU1wSrVztD2//9oYwUgjAUA)

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>29</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
(0{~.\:1#.=)@(</#&,*/)~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3/YqLBdtITSdpkzTFgiC4cuXanbSIGz9A6K/HvBRkCCT33DN5ug2vFkwjKjQgjP7sOU7Xy9nV9F75bRQln9ixPrTlttm1bHWsmO@PF4TEhAUSHXoo6Jz2MTWQ6a1/pQ4pSZrII79FIYki0Qg3QSHJRv//k98@YMgsScpTG6RQCWMSrhcfmwBstFRczDBz6A4wBFgq3Ac)

### how

```
(~. {.@\: 1 #. =)@(</ #&, */)~
                  (</ #&, */)~  NB. all products, dups removed:
                          */    NB. create the times table
                   </           NB. lower triangular ones matrix
                       &,       NB. flatten each and
                      #         NB. filter based on lower triangle
                 @              NB. pass that result to
(~. {.@\: 1 #. =)               NB. get the most frequent list item:
       \:                       NB. sort down
 ~.                             NB. the uniq elements
          1 #. =                NB. by their count
    {.@                         NB. and take the first element
```

Answer (score 2):

### Burlesque - 8 bytes

```
Jcp)pdn!

J        duplicate
 cp      cross product
   )pd   map . product
      n! most common element
```

[Try it online here.](http://cheap.int-e.eu/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=%7B2%203%204%205%206%7DJcp%29pdn%21)

(and yes, Burlesque also has a command for "least common element")

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 95 bytes

```cs
x=>x.SelectMany(y=>(x=x.Skip(1)).Select(z=>y*z)).GroupBy(y=>y).OrderBy(y=>y.Count()).Last().Key
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5NC4JAEL33KzzuxiStVha5eygqoqKgY3QwW0GyVVYl1@i321qewhiYN@/Nmw8/7flpWC1z4bvrhcjvXHqXiLuhyBjUyQgMWhWUFeaRR9zPdp5QSFGGCqqlW5gggnHTQyVlqltqvpJxnsw@RoXNvbxy2TBzHuciQ9qz9VKN5oarato5SH0MBUjwx@n8tMCGAQxh9ML4t@eA1aLWE3aLbv/RCXzDat02AQdIH2oY6zd0SWpX9QY)

Less golfed code:

```cs
// x is a list of integers
x=>
  // iterate over each integer and
  // return a list per element.
  // flatten the list of lists to 1 list
  x.SelectMany(y=>
    // skip the current value and save
    // newly offset list to x so that it
    // can be incrementally offset
    // again next pass
    (x=x.Skip(1))
      // compute the product
      .Select(z=>y*z))
    // get the unique products
    .GroupBy(y=>y)
    // sort the products by number
    // of occurrences
    .OrderBy(y=>y.Count())
    // pick the product with the
    // greatest number of occurrences
    .Last().Key
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
►=mΠṖ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fG5yvnaCtpKBrp6CkUfyoqbFI89C2/4@m7bLNPbfg4c5pRv///4820jHWMdEx1TGL5Yo21zECkiARYyBtDKUNdSDQCCxrpmNkYKBjCERGBlDFYO065joWOhZAEVOgQkuQApAECJoDBS2B0kAhS7AqU7D2WAA)

`►=` gives -1 over the other answer.

`×*` has too many duplicates and doesn't give the right value.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>99</s> 83 bytes

```julia
~=length
!x=argmax(sum.(.==(1:max((M=[x[i]x[j] for i=1:~x for j=i+1:~x])...)),[M]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/PboMwDMbP4ylMtUOiWYg/BQpSpk3atU8Q5YAGawMprQjVsktfnSUBTZNz8M/299np70o2iVmWB1PdeJrPQWhYM50ujSH6folIxBhJaofkyLjhUhjeC/i6TiBZUj@MT3smXxwIGkURpciPgtKlZR/ycybBE08xwz3mWAhgr5CkaGslpivtcZvIPBcOsz@sHCa4RrppvEGBaRxjYl8ab76W/2/DEg94WBV@S24dKidxAy7KtWllNAhujdZdCwwapQhv@WCbDMLBf3EAOcLQ/WjSUkGD2yTHWY1k964UzJ2eNazyGp7XZGcd3/T5@g0hr@wldmvlD8r9zWL5BQ)

-16 bytes (!!) thanks to MarcMush:

- Remove `*` (use implicit multiplication)
- Replace `map` with a broadcast
- Replace `findmax` with `argmax`
- Use the return value of a variable assignment
- Use `sum` instead of `count`

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/BboMwDIbP4ylMtUOiWYjQAgUp0ybt2ieIckCFtYEMKqBadumrsySgaXIO/mz/v532rlXFzLI8uG76y3wNQsOr8fJVGXIe7v0ckYhzwkpXICcujFDSiFbC5zCC4qx8GJ@2XL04kDSKIkpRnCSlS80/1HkmwZNIcI8HTDGTwF@BJWhrOSYrHXCb2HvOHO7/sHDIcI1k03iDDJM4RmZfEm@@lv9vwxyPeFwVfktqHQoncQMu8rVpZTQIbtU0NTVwqLQmohadbXIIO//FDlQPXfMzkZpKGtxG1c@6J7t3rWFupnmCVV7C85rsrOPbdB2@IRSFvcRuLfxBqb9ZLr8 "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online") by removing `*`, avoiding map in favor of broadcasting, reorganizing M and ~, using argmax

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 131 bytes

This code compiles and runs fine on my machine, but not on TIO or ATO... probably because the function leaks a few gigabytes of memory each time.

I've included my test suite below if you'd like to try it for yourself. Run at your own risk!

```c
m,p,T;f(n,z,r,b)int*n,*r,*b;{for(r=calloc(T=~(1<<31),4);z--;n++)for(b=n;b++<n+z;)r[*n**b]++;for(m=p=0;T--;p++)m=r[p]>r[m]?p:m;m=m;}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tests[][9] = {
        {2,3,4,5,6},
        {7,2},
        {2,3,3},
        {3,3,3},
        {1,1,1,1,2,2},
        {6,200,10,120},
        {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8},
        {5,2,9,10,3,4,4,4,7},
        {9,7,10,9,7,8,5,10,1},
    };

    int expected[] = {
        12,
        14,
        6,
        9,
        2,
        1200,
        24,
        20,
        63
    };

    int sizes[] = {5,2,3,3,6,4,8,9,9};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < sizes[i] - 1; j++)
            printf("%d, ", tests[i][j]);
        printf("%d] -> ", tests[i][sizes[i] - 1]);

        int result = f(tests[i], sizes[i]);
        printf("%d\n", result);

        assert(result == expected[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 16 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
⊡1⍖⍘⊚♭×⊞>.⇡⊃⧻⊞×.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqhMeKNluKNmOKKmuKZrcOX4oqePi7ih6HiioPip7viip7Dly4KCmYgWzIgMyA0IDUgNl0KZiBbNyAyXQpmIFsyIDMgM10KZiBbMyAzIDNdCmYgWzEgMSAxIDEgMiAyXQpmIFs2IDIwMCAxMCAxMjBdCmYgWzIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDggOF0KZiBbNSAyIDkgMTAgMyA0IDQgNCA3XQpmIFs5IDcgMTAgOSA3IDggNSAxMCAxXQ==)

```
⊡1⍖⍘⊚♭×⊞>.⇡⊃⧻⊞×.
      ×⊞>.⇡⊃⧻⊞×.  # upper matrix of multiplication table
     ♭            # deshape
⊡1⍖⍘⊚             # number that occurs second most often
```

Comment: -1: `⊢⍖⍘⊚♭≡▽⊞≠.⊃⍏⊞×.` Uses rise to create a no-diagonal mask and keep those elements instead of leaving zeros in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 91 bytes

```php
while($c=$argv[++$i])for($k=$i;--$k;)$r[$c*$argv[$k]]++;asort($r);echo end(array_flip($r));
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61b5256e70486fd943ab74e549b6ded452845088).

Use PHP 7 to avoid STRICT MODE warning.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-h`, 11 bytes

```
à2 ®×Ãü ñÊÌ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=4DIgrtfD/CDxysw=&input=WzIsMyw0LDUsNl0KLWg=)

```
á2 ®×
ñ@è¥X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=4TIgrtcK8UDopVg=&input=WzIsMyw0LDUsNl0KLWg=)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 68 bytes

```javascript
a=>+a.flatMap((x,i)=>a.map(y=>a[y*=i--&&-x]=0+a[y]||[-y])).sort()[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBboMwEEX3nMKryG7GxJgA8cK5QU9gzcJKQ0RF4whQFaTcnQ5JW1FIPV54pOfnP373n749NNWlk@fwdhxKO3i7X/u4rH336i@cX6ESdu/jD2p6Orj@xVZSrlbyilatqcfbzckehYjb0HRcOIXDIZzbUB/jOpx4yZ2GFLaQQY7sdwnBNhuW6GjGFqAn1B92Gz3xpviMzedoAo/SE/0DXSTIQSsFCW2tcJZWqei/2aCAHexwIl7kzeh5M5rHK2MV@MMuvIZ8RJq7NrvHwe/ZUmCFAmYUCw1z1FJn6Ne/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 71 bytes

```powershell
$m=@()
while($l){$k,$l=$l;$m+=($l|%{$k*$_})}($m|group|sort c*)[-1].Name
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmProGGkY6xjomOqY6b5XyUXyNfkKs/IzEnVUMnRrFbJ1gGqUcmxVsnVtgWK1KgChbRU4ms1azVUcmvSi/JLC2qK84tKFJK1NKN1DWP1/BJzU///BwA)

Powershell beats python very occasionally.....

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 48 bytes

```factor
[ dup outer [ 1 + tail ] map-index concat mode ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBT8MwDIXv/RWPM9qUpmtLQeKKuHBBnKYdojRoEVtSElcCVf3txSnrCnIU2d/zs6O8K00@TG@vzy9P9zgrOm75ClabiGg@e@NS9mGCM6dZ/u2JpMhGsjqiC4bouwvWER6ybMgGSBTYoUSFETfYPCKXTGvmS727dBULqRgUf0HDIL@EXJ1pUAUpBHI@UqwbhPi3ucYdx@JK@0pWm2RLLSnqq5ysDdcsNrOznMdfH1egZkXABwxrNWbjtEfbd/A9mYA9O25Byp5w4G/qNta15gvaO60IZ98aHCbm2E4/)

- `dup outer` Take the outer product between the input and itself, forming a matrix
- `[ 1 + tail ] map-index` Get the upper triangle of the matrix without the main diagonal
- `concat` Flatten to a list
- `mode` Find the most frequent number

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 57 bytes

```arturo
$=>[z:combine.by:2&|map=>[∏&]|tally|maximum[k,v][v]z\0]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?BvVweB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ä+G+·♀v▐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=842b472bfa0c76de&i=%5B2,3,4,5,6%5D%0A%5B7,2%5D%0A%5B2,3,3%5D%0A%5B3,3,3%5D%0A%5B1,1,1,1,2,2%5D%0A%5B6,200,10,120%5D%0A%5B2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8%5D%0A%5B5,2,9,10,3,4,4,4,7%5D%0A%5B9,7,10,9,7,8,5,10,1%5D&m=2)

Unpacked:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 bytes

```
2S{{*km:M
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=2S%7B%7B*km%3AM&i=%5B2,3,4,5,6%5D%0A%5B7,2%5D%0A%5B2,3,3%5D%0A%5B3,3,3%5D%0A%5B1,1,1,1,2,2%5D%0A%5B6,200,10,120%5D%0A%5B2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8%5D%0A%5B5,2,9,10,3,4,4,4,7%5D%0A%5B9,7,10,9,7,8,5,10,1%5D&m=2)

```
 S        # Get all combinations of length
2         # 2
  {   m   # And map the following over them:
   { k    # Reduce by
    *     # Multiplication
       :M # Get the mode
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 6 bytes

```
Sđ*aŢṂ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FquCj0zUSjy66OHOpiXFScnFUOEFN6ujjXSMdUx0THXMYrmizXWMgCRIxBhIG0NpQx0INALLmukYGRjoGAKRkQFUMVi7jrmOhY4FUMQUqNASpAAkAYLmQEFLoDRQyBKsyhSsPRbiBgA)

```
Sđ*aŢṂ
S       Subset
 đ      Unpair; check if length is 2, and push the two elements
  *     Multiply
   a    All possible values
    Ţ   Tally; return a list of unique values and a list of their counts
     Ṃ  Find the minimum value by its count
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 53 chars, 106 bytes

```
{0=l←↑⍴⍵:⍵⋄t⊃⍨q⍳⌈/q←{+/t=⍵}¨t←×/¨(∊(⍳l)∘.<⍳l)/,⍵∘.,⍵}
```

Test:

```
  p←{0=l←↑⍴⍵:⍵⋄t⊃⍨q⍳⌈/q←{+/t=⍵}¨t←×/¨(∊(⍳l)∘.<⍳l)/,⍵∘.,⍵}
  p 9
9
  p 1 3
3
  p 2 3 4 5 6
12
  p 7 2
14
  p 2 3 3
6
  p 3 3 3
9
  p 1 1 1 1 2 2
2
  p 6 200 10 120
1200
  p 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8
24
  p 5 2 9 10 3 4 4 4 7
20
  p 9 7 10 9 7 8 5 10 1
63
  p 3 3
9
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 140 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNTwIxEL3zK@bYSm1gEVCQgyYeTNQL8UTMpkIXK7NlbQsRCb99mVJCJNrMTGbevM6XnypU9fL9U08DPCtjYVvPdAEFy3Ew1l@TRxveRHly@YDsaLtWDnCUowzK4DBGixh9aDUbmoKhNP6hrMKGl3LulqvqfsPMTNtgCJKl@qY4l3kmvfnRXOZt0Og1NUVRNptIjIrlFwvOdzVAHKekyZhycz@AO@fUZjIOztg5jQOv1gQYwbYB9NYKwdhqFZEn4wM7oJD8TEBHwJWAroAeF79TfQHZOZLInXOwLeAk2Z8vPUJaLUpGzVr/1Ts2F0ANr0nOOd1D1ZtUIbGT9PmBlmyxdMAQbi/Tpvy4elreaU@rx0PCi0F@zFR0rICWUTZBu0bUXaPeAw)

```scala
def f(_l:Seq[Int],m:Seq[Int]):Int={var l=_l.tail;var k=_l.head;if(l.isEmpty)m.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1 else f(l,m++l.map(_*k))}
```

Ungolfed version.

```scala
object Main {
  def f(_l: List[Int], m: List[Int]): Int = {
    var l=_l.tail;var k=_l.head;
    if (l.isEmpty) m.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
    else f(l, m ++ l.map(_ * k))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = List(
      List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
      List(7, 2),
      List(2, 3, 3),
      List(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
      List(6, 200, 10, 120),
      List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8),
      List(5, 2, 9, 10, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7)
    )
    for (l <- input) {
      val res = f(l, Nil)
      println(res)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Input to the function should be a single list, not split up like this

Comment: @Jo King Thaks for your comment. I  have modified it.