# Is it almost-prime?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, primes

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19269/59642)

**Definition:** A positive integer `n` is *almost-prime*, if it can be written in the form `n=p^k` where `p` is a prime and `k` is also a positive integers. In other words, the prime factorization of `n` contains only the same number.

**Input:** A positive integer `2<=n<=2^31-1`

**Output:** a truthy value, if `n` is *almost-prime*, and a falsy value, if not.

**Truthy Test Cases:**

```
2
3
4
8
9
16
25
27
32
49
64
81
1331
2401
4913
6859
279841
531441
1173481
7890481
40353607
7528289
```

**Falsy Test Cases**

```
6
12
36
54
1938
5814
175560
9999999
17294403
```

Please do not use standard loopholes. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: To clarify: the truthy and falsy values need not be consistent, right?

Comment: Correct. Non-consistent is fine.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144591/prime-powers-of-primes), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167199/recover-the-power-from-the-prime-power), and [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/find-the-maximal-prime-powers). Hopefully gives people some ideas.

Comment: This is [A000961](https://oeis.org/A000961) in the OEIS.

Comment: The usual name for this kind of number is "prime power".

Comment: It feels odd to me that you include prime numbers as being "almost prime," but this is still a good challenge! :)

Comment: This should use the terminology "prime power". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_prime already has a definition.

Comment: Seems to be from Online Judge 10539, which also defines prime powers but calls them "almost primes" (which is a different thing as previously noted).  On the plus side, this definition is much clearer that it is defining prime powers.

Comment: Can we choose instead to output falsy for 'almost prime' numbers and truthy for the others?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## [Sagemath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 2 bytes

```
GF
```

Outputs via [exception](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/48931).

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjc0KwkAMhO-FvsNeRIU5bDbJ_hS86kOoB9EWBKlSK-jbG1Hx4lwymXxJusWmrlbLuqqr7jy43h17tw5gCDIKKCIoQgIHSEG0lEDMhCCeLCJGzFoMKVkIyiRWiBKLkSkX_6riWTn6hKQhh2yHQPYkQgVUOEMzmUuq0aO8ZW0oYpvbpq6caRweH_dSN-vnv-4yHPtxNp0cGsNu7dRN3Hfc3vftZWz-st3udP3AT22yOJg=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

---

The Sagemath builtin \$\text{GF}\$ creates a [Galois Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of order \$n\$. However, remember that \$\mathbb{F}_n\$ is only a field if \$n = p^k\$ where \$p\$ is a prime and \$k\$ a positive integer. Thus the function throws an exception if and only if its input is not a prime power.

Comment: Galois fields was the first thing I thought of, but I had no idea that Sagemath had a builtin for it.

Comment: @DonThousand you should see what you can do with SM, it's support for Elliptic curve math/crypto is fantastic.

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p=2:n%p and f(n,p+1)or p**n%n<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcuxCsIwGEXhPU9xKRSa2sHGLZhXcOjmGGmjAb35iVl8@lgRBXE8cD55lEuiqTW4q7@dZg8O4oxlK/CcEbq1N6NOGdL3bLkf6@Sy53npzLDbaqUkRxY0x@XeqLB@RCQmqxDDi2uL98HP@iWH9C@Yyq@qTw)

Since Python doesn't have any built-ins for primes, we make do with checking divisibility.

We find the smallest prime `p` that's a factor of `n` by counting up `p=2,3,4,...` until `n` is divisible by `p`, that is `n%p` is zero. There, we check that this `p` is the only prime factor by checking that a high power of `p` is divisible by `n`. For this, `p**n` suffices.

As a program:

**43 bytes**

```python
n=input()
p=2
while n%p:p+=1
print p**n%n<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vA1oirPCMzJ1UhT7XAqkDb1pCroCgzr0ShQEsrTzXPxvD/fzMA)

This could be shorter with exit codes if those are allowed.

**46 bytes**

```python
lambda n:all(n%p for p in range(2,n)if p**n%n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcuxCsIwGEXhPU9xKRSS4iB1C/QVHLoJLpE2Gog3P2kWnz5apEJxPZxPXuWR2Fc/XGt0z9vkQOti1GwFPmUIApEd77PuDzTBQ7qOLU0dhy2fjkYpyYEFzWVeGrVCrnC0Ch/iNY3F9@C2/sg5/Qumslf1DQ)

Answer (score 13):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 329 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]
Ajax:Listen tothy.
Page:You cat.
Scene V:.
Page:You is the sum ofYou a cat.
 Is the remainder of the quotient betweenI you nicer zero?If soLet usScene V.
Scene X:.
Page:You is the cube ofYou.Is you worse I?If soLet usScene X.
 You is the remainder of the quotient betweenYou I.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDLCsIwEEV/ZT6gBEQ3diMuXAQKCoIo4iJNpzZiE00m@Pj5mLQFhS7cTS7nzknibtcQMra8iGfGNuKMcZYEPGdbiRrTcFxpQgsJAaErSNQpnfJCOUINZKh5deX8YDxIQUN5l39T5YAaBOdbMHUKRAfyPrbYCqWrqDF1F9y9IYWaoER6IGoOr9jRSkbkjdYseA3OFEjg3SAbpPuxVPoSe2vypUUPY1183HjLnv30/t4qsZytb/ETGhSWQpjNJ9MP)

Outputs `0` if the input is almost prime, and a positive integer otherwise. I am not sure this is an acceptable output; changing it would cost a few bytes.

Explanation:

- Scene I: `Page` takes in input (call this `n`). Initialize `Ajax = 1`.
- Scene V: Increment `Ajax` until `Ajax` is a divisor of `Page`; call the final value `p` This gives the smallest divisor of `Page`, which is guaranteed to be a prime.
- Scene X: Cube `Ajax` until you end up with a power of `p`, say `p^k` which is greater than `n`. Then `n` is almost-prime iff `n` divides `p^k`.

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the space after "the remainder of", right?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye No, that space is needed, as the name of the function is `the_remainder_of_the_quotient_between`. If you remove the space in the middle of the name, the function is not applied.

Comment: Right, okay. I'd forgotten about that function

Answer (score 12):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
Yf&=
```

- For almost-primes the output is a matrix containing only `1`s, which is [truthy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398).
- Otherwise the output is a matrix containing several `1`s and at least one `0`, which is [falsy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzJNzfb/fxMDY1NjMwNzAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bY47T8QwEIT7@RVuIJcmyvoR2wWiOZDoKK6hQCICh1g4D8WJ0BX89mByEroTbLPe8bcz29VzWF/Yb12x/VAUxWfrg1ufmuub9fb886FBdpiWuT1m2/y4xJbNrY8szpPv3/F1Tt@F6JDd1yFu@H/88wXfv7Gdb3LsLw7ycQz1EYdz8WQ0LY7tNruu/nAxOTu2nc7CMIzM943v/exysD8xG5anuG4M/tXP@cohIGFgQRW4AtcQHNKiSiqBhCBwWVKSSKAyyibEGklQgmRqRFrIRGpjy58uS6FEVWpoxQ03yQiUQiooCbLCQBlKL61UVcKeKo3cyrT5DQ), including truthiness/falsihood test.

#### How it works

```
     % Implicit input
Yf   % Prime factors. Gives a vector with the possibly repeated prime factors
&=   % Matrix of all pair-wise equality comparisons
     % Implicit output
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 11 bytes

```
PrimePowerQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1LCoNQELtKDxDwze@9mUXBI9gjSBHrwhZE6KL07Hak2SQTksw67o9pHfflPh7z9Ri2ZZ2G13vabqd@7peun7v@wxAoHAGqYAM3CEMDNV0CiRBYC6VFguoWGQlXgglpElETzWTzKCdrEZNaGpqxs@cQKJ9UmIJCHOaUqpnVgvgjTw7N5vc4fg)

@Sisyphus saved 1 byte

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÒË
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KTD3f//mxgYmxqbGZgDAA)

#### Commented:

```
Ò   -- Are all the primes in the prime decomposition
 Ë  -- Equal?
```

Comment: A pure ASCII alternative: [`fg`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Lf3/fxMDY1NjMwNzAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") - since only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>36</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

*-3 bytes by outputting a vector of booleans without extracting the first element*

```r
!(a=2:(n=scan()))[!n%%a]^n%%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X1Ej0dbISiPPtjg5MU9DU1MzWjFPVTUxNg5I5v03tPgPAA)

Outputs a vector of booleans. In R, a vector of booleans is truthy iff the first element is `TRUE`.

First, find the smallest divisor `p` of `n`. We can do this by checking all integers (not only primes), as the smallest divisor of an integer (apart from 1) is always a prime number. Here, let `a` be all the integers between `2` and `n`, then `p=a[!n%%a][1]` is the first element of `a` which divides `n`.

Then `n` is almost prime iff `n` divides `p^n`.

This fails for any moderately large input, so here is the previous version which works for most larger inputs:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```r
!log(n<-scan(),(a=2:n)[!n%%a])%%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XzEnP10jz0a3ODkxT0NTRyPR1sgqTzNaMU9VNTFWU1XV8L@RuaWFieF/AA)

Compute the logarithm of `n` in base `p`: this is an integer iff `n` is almost prime.

This will fail due to floating point inaccuracy for certain (but far from all) large-ish inputs, in particular for one test case: \$4913=17^3\$.

Comment: Brilliant and 25 bytes less than my own best attempt without peeking...  The log trick is super!

Comment: Although a nice approach, I'm afraid it fails for test case `4913` due to floating point inaccuracies (`2.9999999999999996` is not an integer). I've just looked in the meta, and apparently you have to work around this if your language supports an accurate decimal type. I don't know R, so I don't know if this applies to it, but I was about to port your approach to Java to golf my about to post answer, but that apparently wouldn't be allowed unless I use `java.math.BigDecimal` instead of regular doubles.. :/

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I assumed this was OK, as it would work with a theoretical infinite-precision computer. I am probably not aware of the meta consensus you referred to, could you link to it?

Comment: @RobinRyder Ah, I thought I added a link. [Here it is.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16510/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I'll follow the advice [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16254/86301) and add a notice that it fails for certain large-ish inputs due to floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: Looks like port of your Shakespearean solution (which is also great) is the same number of bytes in R ```!(a=2:(n=scan()))[!n%%a][1]^(3*n)%%n``` (although even worse than this at handling large inputs)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen While you were commenting, I made a similar change: I don't need  `…^(3*n)` but simply `…^n`, which gains 4 bytes (but fails for any moderately large input).

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

```c
f(n,i){for(i=1;n%++i;);n=i<n&&f(n/i)^i?:i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU/bTsMwDH3GXxFN6pSoQcv9QlbxIWNIU0eRH8jQ6BNVv704QCTHzjnHJ/b4@D6O2zbxKlEs0@3OcdCldn2PRZQ64LHu98QeULzi8xOWdfu4YOViAawzm09nNrAFjAQrwUlIErIEHSQYTxEJJ84RFhqribOWbuOUbrimtpB8btqcHGHeatey1tG61hBTVr@FU9bboMgzepNMaqaka39T9uSvs6UBfNKtjt4HReP8nQaY7MgD1gK0KONtARxUweMXfr/dJj6Lw39FlCjY9wIePu/0mPiuy1fWXV/qTs4nPEtSUxKiwLr9AA)

Returns `p` if `n` is almost-prime, and `1` otherwise.

```c
f(n,i){
    for(i=1;n%++i;);    // identify i = the least prime factor of n
    n=i<n&&f(n/i)^i     // if n is neither prime nor almost-prime
      ?                 //  return 1
      :i;               // return i
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
⊢∊⍳∘.∧⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw9CsJgEET7nGIuoHy7m5ikFsRUgnqBgKhFQPGnSC2EEIhoIdjY2Ghn4Q08yl4krqYZBubNS9dZZ5an2WrR6PGSjLQ4uUaru5aV1m8tr10tH9aauS1aH7U6fF6ixdnoybhvOR0mk0brG6ab/W6Ze/PPEwyBjwAhIsQgAgmoBwpBMVjAATgExxCC8P9CYp19R97PNUizbauylwMxyAcFoAjswEayweAeOII4iLSSWAwInfsC)

Uses `⎕IO←0`. Returns 0 if the input is almost-prime, 1 otherwise.

#### How it works

```apl
⊢∊⍳∘.∧⍳    ⍝ Input: integer n ≥ 2
  ⍳∘.∧⍳    ⍝ Generate a table of LCMs over 0..n-1
⊢∊         ⍝ Does the table contain n?
```

The LCM of two numbers is equivalent to taking the maximum of powers in their prime factorizations. If `n = p^k`, any numbers smaller than `n` cannot have `p^k` in their prime factorization, so the LCM table does not contain `n`. Otherwise, we can find a pair of coprime numbers under `n` that multiplies to `n`, so the LCM table is guaranteed to contain at least one copy of `n`.

Comment: Can't you just check whether `n` divides LCM(`1`..`n-1`)?

Comment: @Neil It isn't APL golf-friendly: `0=⊢|1∧/⍤↓⍳`, 10 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>33</s> <s>31</s> 26 bytes

```apl
{⍵∊∊(((⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳)⍵)∘*¨⍳⍵}
```

-5 bytes from Kevin Cruijssen's suggestion.

*Warning:* Very, very slow for larger numbers.

### Explanation

```apl
{⍵∊∊(((⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳)⍵)∘*¨⍳⍵} ⍵=n in all the following steps
                       ⍳⍵  range from 1 to n
                    ∘*¨    distribute power operator across left and right args
    (((⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳)⍵)       list of primes till n
   ∊                       flatten the right arg(monadic ∊)
 ⍵∊                        is n present in the primes^(1..n)?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/@lHv1kcdXUCkoaHxqGtR3aOOGXqHpz/qXaFp@Kht8qPezZpAFZpAUa1DK4A8IKf2f9qjtgmPevsedTU/6l3zqHfLofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/6cpGHGlKRgDsQkQmwGxIVjADAA)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can drop the `*0.5` and just use a range or 1 to n?

Comment: It is way too slow with that but yeah, sure.

Comment: Well, codegolf is all about saving bytes, so compilation warnings, code standards, and performance are all irrelevant in code-golfing. Even if the performance would go from \$O(1)\$ to \$O(n^n)\$, if we can save even a single byte it's worth it, haha. ;)

But if TIO would be to slow to run, you could leave the `*0.5` in the TIO and mention it's only used to speed up the online code. (PS: The `0.5` could have been golfed to `.5` if it was indeed required.)

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>9</sup> 8 bytes

```
1=#@=@q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU1BCgIxELv3FUEPi6Cl05lpOwuFBcGTJ78ginhY8bivX0fEQEgmJMxz3cThjj5iwB4Jo/MQcbycTyv17dSn97juwtJjBkPQYKCCrMgVnCGG4imBmAlZEnlEjNLUvGJNCMokLkSVxZu1WfqqJFYuqaJqbrlZmHssIP9ToAIybtBG7qpqSbAf/MwmPg7hdn28cMfyN3NYPw)

*-1 byte thanks to xash*

Tests if the [self-classify](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/eq#monadic) `=` of the prime factors `q:` has length `#` equal to one `1=`

Answer (score 6):

### [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```
gniomh(n){p:=2nuair-a n%p p+=1nuair-a n>1 n/=p toradh n==1}
```

[Try it here](https://try-setanta.ie/editor/EhEKBlNjcmlwdBCAgIDAzs2RCg)

Notes:

- The proper keyword is `gníomh`, but Setanta allows spelling it without the accents so I did so to shave off a byte.

Comment: What an interesting language! Makes me want to go try to learn Irish again, and Setanta, for that matter!

Comment: We usually count bytes in characters, since the size of a byte depends on the machine's hardware.

Comment: `í` (with the acute) is 2 bytes in UTF-8 while `i` is only one.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
!t{P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X7GkOuD/f3MjSwA)

Explanation:

```
P - List of prime factors
{ - Remove duplicate elements
t - Removes first element
! - Would return True if remaining list is empty, otherwise False
```

*-1 byte, thanks to hakr14*

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing, but does [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1hPOyDw/38TA2NTYzMDcwA) work?

Comment: @UnrelatedString that does, but I am not sure if im allowed to do that since it returns 0 (falsy value) for right cases and a truthy value for the others (which isn't fixed either).

Comment: Well, in that case, `!s.+PQ` is still a byte shorter.

Comment: `Q` can be omitted at the end, Pyth will fill missing variables with it (or the first lambda variable if inside a lambda)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

### Without BigInts

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=(n,k=1)=>n%1?!~~n:f(n<0?n/k:n%++k?n:-n,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZG9bsJAEIT7vAUFsk@EcOv78Z2FcccTpCMpLIITsLWOMERKw6sbUJoks1d@N9qd2TnUX/WwPe4/T3Pu33bj2JQpP7YlqXLFU6omlwsXTcpLXfGiLXg6m7UVF/ObRo3bnoe@2z11/XuabJ6P59PH92uiHn7zJs3Uf2KAWCABSARCHlDmEOVoAD1ZHO8FV4QmjEGYWU3CCsLkPrgoWI7B4gBnyAo4D1FbwZnVxhmv7/H//CQvvFnX3SB0hQcloT5UOTwVRYMdukCCMnfOa@z75wnyLNpbNqXGKw)

A recursive function that first looks for the smallest divisor \$k>1\$ of \$n\$ and then divides \$-n\$ by \$k\$ until it's not an integer anymore. (The only reason why we invert the sign of \$n\$ when \$k\$ is found is to distinguish between the two steps of the algorithm.)

If \$n\$ is almost-prime, the final result is \$-\dfrac{1}{k}>-1\$. So we end up with \$\lceil n\rceil=0\$.

If \$n\$ is not almost-prime, there exists some \$q>k\$ coprime with \$k\$ such that \$n=q\times k^{m}\$. In that case, the final result is \$-\dfrac{q}{k}<-1\$. So we end up with \$\lceil n\rceil<0\$.

---

## JavaScript (ES11), 33 bytes

### With BigInts

With BigInts, using [@xnor's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210174/58563) is probably the shortest way to go.

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=(n,k=1n)=>n%++k?f(n,k):k**n%n<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDJDoJAEATQu/9BYEANzTAsRvTmF3hDDwTBBdJjAE38elxO6tT1pZOqrktxL/qyO1@HGetDNY515vC0yYhFtmLL85p1/QaxaFyXLV7SWGrudVvNW3107Hzb3YbTY2@LybfXTsDin6RJoUmJSalJFJkWKGAx6AG6hSAjQu0IdJESaBD6hHIIzBAl6pP/w/aO803R9mBc8DyhwcGdAk9RKsHqKiF0GysV@S8fnw)

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to H.PWiz; the explanation for why this worked was more complicated*
*-1 bytes by returning to the original algorithm (with its simple explanation), by actually constructing values of \$a\$ not divisible by \$b\$ (32 bytes) instead of asserting \$a\$ is not divisible by \$b\$ (35 bytes); this is slower, but not exponentially so*

```
^(?!(((x+)x+)(?=\2+$)\2*\3)\1+$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LbsIwEEV/BaIKZkgTElp1gWtYdcGGRbtsWsmCwZnWOJZtHuXx7WlYVKp0F1c6V7o6X2qvwsqzi1lwvCa/bew3/bReWjr0Xkm/HB3ASc7Go/YT5n0AOKbYBeaymqR3WE1G1QNWZVfb0fiEeWzeomerAfNgeEXwdJ89IoogC3Go2RCAkZ7U2rAlQOxLuzMGz1qaPDjDEYbZEAVvAKzUuSGrY42zyeXCYamWwNIpH2hhI@j34gPxD9B/YGflvJzeMMbaN4dkYffK8LrnldU07SWpEZvGg@BnSYLTFLvD5JjknhypCIz5VsVVDR7xHAYD1ylFuFmUwu1iiL6biOu1LbOyKIpf)

The 35 byte version was [written in 2014](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1177373) by teukon and me.

This works by asserting that there do not exist any \$a\$ and \$b\$, both proper divisors of \$n\$ where \$a>b\$, for which \$a\$ is not divisible by \$b\$.

This will always be true when \$n\$ is of the form \$p^k\$ (a prime power), because we will have \$a=p^c\$ and \$b=p^d\$ where \$k > c > d \ge 0\$, thus \$a\$ will always be divisible by \$b\$.

But if \$n\$ is not of the form \$p^k\$, there will always be at least one counterexample \$a,b\$ such that \$a\$ is not divisible by \$b\$. Trivially we can choose two different prime factors of \$n\$, and they will not be mutually divisible.

This algorithm is similar to that used by [Original Original Original VI's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220047/17216).

```
# For the purpose of these comments, the input number will be referred to as N.
^(?!              # Assert that the following cannot match
    (             # Capture \1 to be the following:
        ((x+)x+)  # Cycle through all values of \3 and \2 such that \2 > \3 > 1
        (?=\2+$)  # such that \2 is a proper divisor of N
        \2*\3     # Cycle through all values of \1 > \2 that aren't divisible
                  # by \2, by letting \1 = \2 * A + \3 where A >= 0
    )
    \1+$          # where \1 is a proper divisor of N
)
```

---

Bonus: Here is a 28 (27) byte regex that matches numbers of the form \$p^k\$ where \$0 \le k \le 2\$:
`^(?!((x+)x+)(?!\1*\2+$)\1+$)`, exponential slowdown  version: `^(?!((x+)+)(?!\1*\2+$)\1+$)`
(`(x+)+)` is equivalent to `(x+)x*` but exponentially slower)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9PawIxFMS/ii5F33O760ZKD6bRUw9ePLTH2kLQZ/a1MRuS@KdqP/t2PRQKwzDwGxjmUx90XAf2qYieNxR2jfui7zYoR8feC5nnkwc4q9l41H7AvA9wyrFTF1ditJrkd7gSnbWj8RnL1LymwM4AltHymuDxvnhAlFFV8lizJQCrAumNZUeA2Fduby1ejLJl9JYTDIshSt4COGVKS86kGmeT65XjUi@Bldch0sIlMG/VO@IfoP/AzcRcTG8YUx2aY7ZwB2150wvaGZr2stzKbRNA8pMiyXmO3WB2yspAnnQCxnKn07qGgHiJg4HvLiW4vRDS71NMoavIn59WFKKqql8)

This is interesting because if I'd set out to implement that function intentionally, I would have come up with something like [`^(?=(x?x+?)\1*$)((?=(x+)(\3+$))\4)?\1$`](https://tio.run/##TY/NTsJAFEZfBRsC91JbWiUuGIeuXLBhoUuqyQQu7dVhOpkZoPLz7BVMTFx@OV9ycj7VXvmVYxsSb3lNbtuYL/runDR06L1S9dJagKOcjUfdBxQS2qKNCyzzUR/hd8cI5WPcRywnWJR5vxuNj5iG5i04NhVg6jWvCJ7ukwmi8DITh5o1AWjpSK01GwLEO2l2WuOpkjr1VnOAYTJEwRsAI6tUk6lCjbOH85n9Qi2ApVXO09wEqJbZO@IfoP/AzPIin94whto1h2hu9krzuueUqWjai2ItNo0Dwc@SBMcxXoVRG6WOLKkAjOlWhVUNDvHkBwN7TQpwq8iF3QUf3PUiLpcuS/Isy34A) (38 bytes), which is 10 bytes longer.

It was inspired by the algorithm used by [Bubbler's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220062/17216). The full prime power version of that would be:
[`^(?!((x+)(?=\2+$)x+)(?!\1*\2+$)\1+$)`](https://tio.run/##TY9Lb8IwEIT/CkQV7JImJKjqAddw6oELh/ZYWsmCxdnWOJZtHuXx29OAhNTLaEbfSKP5VjsVlp5dzILjFflNbX/ot/HS0r7zRvr14ACOcjIcNF8w7QIcUoSpXIzSB7zZ7qIc3NKibKUZDI@Yx/o9erYaMA@GlwTPj9kTogiyEPuKDQEY6UmtDFsCxK60W2PwpKXJgzMcoZ/1UfAawEqdG7I6VjgZnc8c5moOLJ3ygWY2gv4oPhHvgP4DOymn5fiKMVa@3iczu1OGVx2vrKZxJ0mNWNceBL9IEpym2A4mhyT35EhFYMw3Ki4r8Iin0Ou59lKE64tSuG0M0bcVcbk0ZVYWRfEH) - ECMAScript, 36 bytes
[`^(?!((x+)x+)\B(?>\1*?(?<=^\2+))$)`](https://tio.run/##ZVBNaxsxEL3nV8imYE33g11DL1Vkhyw9BBIS6kAPdQPqeuIIZO2i0bqKN/ntrryb5JJBl@G90fuoKasbh0erdkitqpGtnsnjru9I2y2rZNVYagyKcb/H4POfuO2Mcj9C65BIR4KojSJiu5688rpm@0Zv2I3SlnHo98oxkhfT4wNfTjgPCcS3vuTLxbr8uuTLc/mwnicAX@A4FSeykxb/saiCgVO@6v6Sd1Gclynl12i3/imbQzrgt60/6edVs2u1wQ2IkcuMeGwc19YzKwvBjayibbW51hY5wETazhhhZQm9fuR2UUCV/3La40gYbLTS5KvWaM9n2QzE6S@dojiLB@2bj8X85WUSgfzePd8pR8jb38WftOkiFT5D72dZOXIQ3mX59MrulYmtOWW3@J31xes0NSDQEA4NhqGU1djELMxSDR8RDzGiPpcodJKkIZERhujS5Vd0o3z9xAMMOQ@fch5kKT4sDJrhzSOI12GOZfatKP4D) - .NET, 33 bytes
[`^(?!((x+)+)\B(?>\1*?(?<=^\2+))$)`](https://tio.run/##ZZBPT@MwFMTv@yncCql@mz9qKnHBuF1txAEJtGiLxIEukkkfxZLrRH5OMQ189q6bABd8s2bs@c1UlFW1w4NVW6RGVciWr@Rx27Wk7YaVsqwt1QbFcL/F4PO/uGmNchehcUiko0FURhGxbUdeeV2xXa3X7Fppyzh0O@UYyV/jwwNfjDgPCSSw@s0X81Xxc8EX5/JhNUsATuAwFkevkxZfWAzBwClfto/kXczmRUr5FdqNf85mkPb6n8Yf4/Oy3jba4BrE4GVGPNWOa@uZlVPBjSwjtVpfaYscYCRta4ywsoBOP3E7n0KZ3zntcTD0GI00@bIx2vNJNgFx/EunKH7EB80Hx3z29jaKQn7rXm@UI@TN/fRfWrfRCt@lz2dZMXgQPmP5@NLulImjOWU3eMa66fs4NSDQEPYDhn6U5bDEJExSDV8V97GiPpcodJKkIZFRhkjp8ku6Vr565gH6nvtvPfeyEF8IfWb4YATx3p9Dkc1O/wM) - .NET, 32 bytes,  exponential slowdown

And [user41805's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220353/17216) ported to regex is:
[`^(?!(xx+)\1*(?=\1*$)x(xx+)\2*$(?<=^\2+))`](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsIwEER/pY2QvEuIFXOMMTn1wIVDeyxFWIkJW7lOahuIBHx7GlpV4rIa7ZvdmU990qHy1MXMtbUZgsqlV6@meek7eIueXMO9Pu@GLZTP0PcpbsQUSjXOCfZ/i/l0AuVCbTfzFHHY8WCpMiBmmUCU3nwfyRtg3ujakjMMeTXqaFYuGr/Xo/VCrjvGovNtZULgIdbkbshbB@z3YmbV8tIoy0NnKQLLGEraAzjVcGtcEw@4nF@vFNZ6DaQ67cP9OzTv@QfiPzCPwC1FKYo7xnjw7TlZuZO2VD957RpTPCWplfvWg6SFMpLSFMfApE@4N91YHgj5l47VATzi5aF4e4z87CkagFCyjWMFY5gSyqCEvN1wEJnI8/wH) - ECMAScript 2018, 40 bytes
`^(?!(?*(xx+)\1*$)(xx+)\2*(?=\2*$)x\1*$)` - ECMAScript + `(?*)`, 39 bytes

The algorithm used by 10+ of the other answers (that all the prime factors are the same / there is only one prime factor), ported to regex is:
[`^(?=(xx+?)\1*$)(?!(\1x+)(?<!^\3+(xx+))\2*$)`](https://tio.run/##Tc69bsIwFAXgV4Goku9tiBXTLcZk6sDC0I5NEVZiwq1cJ7UNRAKenYZKldiO9N2f86WPOtSe@pi5rjG3oHLp1ZtpX4ce3qMn13KvT9vbBkoFw5CWWInnJ4RyCpUY0jEsppvqJb0bYjUf7bblwVJtQMwygSi9@TmQN8C80Y0lZxjyeszRrFw0fqfH0TO5/hCL3ne1CYGH2JC7Iu8csL@NmVXLc6ssD72lCCxjKGkH4FTLrXFt3ONyfrlQWOs1kOq1D/fr0H7kn4j/YB7BLUUpijtj3PvulKzcUVtqJl671hSTJLVy13mQtFBGUpri@DAZEu5NP5YHQv6tY70Hj3h@KN4dIj95igYglKxyrGAMU0IZlJDXK97mmcjz/Bc) - ECMAScript 2018, 43 bytes

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
.+
$*
^(?!(((1+)1+)(?=\2+$)\2*\3)\1+$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYoxCsMwEMB2/aKQwDmGwN05bjyUjPmECc2QoUuH0v87Bg1C6Hf9P9@zjbK/2xwZJg7ZHiKiMXRke1WLQ6g2VQ9Vu7ZmOImVgmZswZ64kQq5V0XdlYz2LbMktPh6Aw)

Comment: How about `^(?!((x+)(?=\2*$)x+)(?!\2*$)\1+$)`?

Comment: @H.PWiz Thanks! It's more complicated to explain, but that often seems to be the case with better golfs. I still have a backlog of ones to explain from both you and Grimmy!

Answer (score 3):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 48 bytes

Port of @RobinRyder's R answer.

```
method(i,c :=2;while(i%c>0,c=c+1);i log(c)%1==0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY1NDoMgGAX37xSExARSF36AVmvoEXoCN5ZiJcGfqE2PbzlD3@7NYiYs58BulnXn5I9xeYmQu/RV@x1D9CJk7l7kzroLyTawuLyFkxlZW8iTK2gY1GhAFVQJdYVWMA2qRAmkNUGZghIizdm@xnAI3s1csqlfRb8/PtPTb5INy@Z7N6Y2WNoggmTrFuYjzpDgFSilKpQG1OgaZU3mb935Aw)

### Explanation

```
method(i,            // Take an input
    c := 2           // Set counter to 2
    while(i%c>0,     // While the input doesn't divide counter:
        c=c+1        //     Increment counter
    )
    i log(c)%1==0    // Is the decimal part of input log counter equal to 0?
)
```

Answer (score 3):

## GAP 4.7, 31 bytes

`n->Length(Set(FactorsInt(n)))<2`

This is a lambda. For example, the statement

`Filtered([2..81], n->Length(Set(FactorsInt(n)))<2 );`

yields the list `[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61, 64, 67, 71, 73, 79, 81 ]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S08s@B9QlJlXouGWmVOSWpSaohFtpKdnYRir8z9P184nNS@9JEMjOBUon5hckl9U7AlUmqepqWlj9F9T0/o/AA)

Comment: Please link your answers to [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#gap) or any other interpreter so they can be verified properly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
f n=mod(until((<1).mod n)(+1)2^n)n<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBCoAgEADAr@yhgxKJeq6XRIGYlrRuYvb9tuY2h7vPgMgcgaZ8beKhllCI0Uj1F0iK3ki7kqTRcHaJYIJSEzXoICZsoUKE2SpltF749RHdfvPgS/kA)

**36 bytes**

```hs
f n=and[mod(gcd d n^n)n<2|d<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgEATAr2xhoQUErfUlBBPCiRLhJGjp2z1nDn@fW84iEbx4Jlsu6vdAIPDKA8/TS7Oyo9bsnBSfGAtqS/ygQ0z52Roi7KT1aIyTL8Ts91tUqPUH)

**39 bytes**

```hs
f n=all((`elem`[1,n]).gcd n.(^n))[2..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEADAr@yhg0KJdvclYiSmJm2LpO9vo7nOGfqVEJkzkA2IQuwJ0707M5OXqsQDSImNpHSrUuT5DpXAQnsqDZggVxzpgQx/G609vzFjKJ2X2NoH)

**39 bytes**

```hs
f n=mod n(n-sum[1|1<-gcd n<$>[1..n]])<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADAr3Rw0AFincGPEAaCoESoRHTz7VZvvM21PeTMHIF0ORagnkS7i8EHlVj9H6qbDUpJ1g4KubhEoKGeiS7oIKZ8hRMimElKHEfLr4/ZrY2Fr/UD)

**40 bytes**

```hs
f n=and[mod(p^n)n<1|p<-[2..n],mod n p<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDkAwEAXQq/yFBQmi1u1JpJKGlkaNCV06u8H25a3u2nxKIgFkHM3Dfswlj1SRVjfrZujblmz9KQislZXdRYIBn5EyCoSYsj8R8E/VdVaeKSS3XNJMzC8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```
: f ( n -- ? ) factors all-equal? ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU@7TsNAEOznK7aEwpb33ucUKVGaNIgKUVjm7ERcbGM7BYr4drOAKNhmZkcz@@iadh3n7enxcHyo6S3NQ8o0zWldP6b5PKx0adZTKfSSlrL7MS/Uz@N1Og89Len9moY2LbTD4VhTO76mfszdVlNHdzRQUdCe7ukv2ORcSKTJe9ptN1LQMAiIYAdloTy0golwojJYa4YyFYvEGi7YKJYYDMNqNgLMXhtx@hCrbzSVttpVHt6qoEKkT3qWS17ki4lK4EYOLFsdrAFHHWADC/PWugrxt6RV0cio/@ntCw)

Comment: @petStorm Here it is :) Thanks!

Comment: Save 13 bytes by ditching the named function. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU67TsNAEOz5ivkBrNvbe0JBuogmTZQKpTisS7CwHXM@F1GUbzcLiG3moVnNnFJbL2U97F932yd85jLmHlPJtV6n0o0VQ6ofjdAhz83pNzzjXC7L1I1nzPlryWObZzw/3KDBMAiIIAdtoT1Yw0Q4cQnETNBGkVjEcMFGicRgCJbJCBB5NpL0IaofNIotO@XhrQ46RNylxYGkyMEaUOQAG0iYt9YpxL8TqaORb9zXN/yvTn3/KHtT/4Kj2EOa0OCIdinlivdus34D "Factor – Try It Online")

Comment: @chunes Thanks! I didn't know it's allowed when I posted it. I have at least dozen more submission using this form.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>69</s> 64 bytes

```java
n->{int f=0,t=1;for(;n%++t>0;);for(;n>1;n/=t)f|=n%t;return f<1;}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@Deadcode*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LVDBjoIwEL37FRMTEwijS2kLrV38g/Xi0XioCBtcLAaqm43Lt7PDag@dvtfXN69ztne7PJ@@xqKxfQ8ftnaPGUDtfNlVtihhO0GAY9s2pXVQBHQFLjTEDjPaem99XcAWHOQwuuXmMQmqPEafM1O1XWDcIor8JjbhC26YcW@5D6vf3C286Up/6xxU78wMo5k8r7djQ54v63tbn@BCwYKd72r3uT@ADZ@pJr@pXb125fcUen94JMhRoEKNLMVEYpIhT1BoTIllyDhnmIiYEcU4pkpqkmglGErOBBXGMi5ImSkdT1XEXPI0zjCTiUoUGSGjJilKgUxzhVIxOmVSpjHq5yKYaEEvh/A/KMDup/flZdXe/OpKv/CNC@povoZ55FY01PA10WH8Aw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{             // Method with integer parameter and boolean return-type
  int f=0,       //  Flag-integer `f`, starting at 0
      t=1;       //  Temp integer `t`, starting at 1
  for(;n%++t>0;);//  Increase `t` by 1 before every iteration with `++t`,
                 //  And continue looping until the input `n` is divisible by `t`
  for(;n>1;      //  Then start and continue a second loop as long as `n` is not 0 or 1:
      n/=t)      //    After every iteration: divide `n` by `t`
    f|=          //   Bitwise-OR the flag by:
       n%t;      //    `n` modulo-`t`
  return f<1;}   //  After both loops, return whether the flag is still 0
```

---

If we would be allowed to ignore floating point inaccuracies, a port of [*@RobinRyder*'s R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210175/52210) would be **64 bytes** as well:

```java
n->{int m=1;for(;n%++m>0;);return Math.log(n)/Math.log(m)%1==0;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVDLbsIwELzzFatKSImypPErsYnCH5QLR8TBhEBDEwclhqpC@Xa6Kag@eB@enRnv2d7s4nz4epSNHQb4sLW7zwBq56v@aMsK1lMJsO@6prIOyoCewIU5dccZXYO3vi5hDQ4KeLjF6j4B2oLlx64PcjePonaV5GHeV/7aO1Lwn3HTnQIXvv/nbThnRZHk4yOfOC/XfUOcL@pbVx@gJWPBxve1O213YMOnq0likquXrvqeTG93d44CJWo0yFLkCnmGgqM0mFKXIROCIZcJoxYTmGplCGK0ZKgEkxQYy4QkZKZNMkWZCCXSJMNMcc01ESEjkRSVRGaERqUZZZlSaYLmeajkRtLkGP4ZBdj8DL5q4@7q4wv9wjcuqKO3JbxFLqalhq@Njo9f)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{               // Method with integer parameter and boolean return-type
  int m=1;         //  Minimum divisor integer `m`, starting at 1
  for(;n%++m>0;);  //  Increase `m` by 1 before every iteration with `++m`
                   //  And continue looping until the input `n` is divisible by `m`
  return Math.log(n)/Math.log(m)
                   //  Calculate log_m(n)
         %1==0;}   //  And return whether it has no decimal values after the comma
```

But unfortunately this approach fails for test case `4913` which would become `2.9999999999999996` instead of `3.0` due to floating point inaccuracies (it succeeds for all other test cases).
A potential fix would be **71 bytes**:

```java
n->{int m=1;for(;n%++m>0;);return(Math.log(n)/Math.log(m)+1e9)%1<1e-8;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVDBbsIwDL3vKywkpFY1rG6SNqGDP4ALR8QhQGFlbYrawDShfjtzB1oOsf3y7Pfis73Zyfnw9dhXtutgaUt3fwMonS/ao90XsBpKgF3TVIV1sA/4CVyYM9q/8dV568s9rMDBHB5usrgPhHpO@bFpg9yNo6hexHmYt4W/ti5YWv85rZpT4ML3/7wOIypMOKYPKiY67x/5MPpy3VU8@qVwa8oD1OwvWPu2dKfNFmz4NDcoDarlzBXfg/fN9p6gQIkaDVKKicIkQ5GgNJgySkhCECYyJoZIYKqVYYrRklAJkhyIMiGZmWkTD1HGQok0zjBTiU40D0JikRSVRDJCo9LEWaZUGqN5Hi4TI7mzD/@MAqx/Ol/U0@bqpxf@ha9cUEajGYwiN@Xdhq/F9o9f)

Comment: 65 bytes, no floating point: [`n->{int r=n,o=1,t=1;for(;t++<r;)for(o=r;r%t<1;)r/=t;return o==n;}`](https://tio.run/##LVDBbsIwDL3zFRbSpFY1rGmStiF0fzAuHBGHUMpUVhKUBqYJ9ds7d5BDbL88P7/4bO5mcT5@j3Vn@h4@TWsfM4DWhsafTN3AZioBDs51jbFQR/QENtaEDjO6@mBCW8MGLFQw2sXHYyL4yqKrGIaK6ZPzkQ5JsvY6nnJXee3fwprp2L9XQfsm3LwFV1VWD6OeRK@3Q0eiL@27a49wIWfRNvjWfu32YOKnrUlvmteubPMzud7tHwwz5CiwRIUsx0xiViDPUCjMCWXIOCeOSBlBjGNeSkUUVQqGkjNBgbGCC2IWpUqnKFIueZ4WWMiszEoSQkZDcpQCmeIlypJRVkiZp6ieh8pMCeoc4n@rANvfPjSXpbuF5ZX@ETobtcl8BfPELmmv8Wupw/gH) – and as a bonus it can be controlled whether it returns true or false for n=1.

Comment: 64 bytes, no floating point: [`n->{int c=0,t=1;for(;n%++t>0;);for(;n>1;n/=t)c|=n%t;return c<1;}`](https://tio.run/##LVDLbsIwELzzFSskpERZaPxKbNzwB@XCEXEwIVShwUGJoapovp1uCj54PePx7HhP7ubmp8PXo2xc38OHq/19AlD7UHVHV1awHiHAvm2bynkoI7oCH1tihwltfXChLmENHgp4@PnqPgrKIsVQMHtsu8j6WZKEVWrjF1wx69@KEJe/hZ8F21Xh2pHzO7PDw46el@u@Ic@X9a2tD3CmYNEmdLX/3O7Axc9Uo9/Yrl766nsMvd3dOQqUqNEgy5Ar5DkKjtJgRixDJgRDLlNGFBOYaWVIYrRkqASTVBjLhSRlrk06VpkKJbI0x1xxzTUZIaMmGSqJzAiNSjM65UplKZrnIsiNpJdD/B8UYPPTh@q8aK9hcaFfhMZHdTJdwjTxCxpq/Jro8PgD) – like the floating point version, it infinitely loops for n=1.

Comment: @Deadcode Thanks! Nice approach. I've kept in the second inaccurate answer for now, but it's nice you've found an equal-bytes way without any floating inaccuracies.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>50</s> 43 bytes

```
.+
$*
^(?=(11+?)\1*$)((?=(1+)(\3+$))\4)*\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDkIhEAX7dw5MdiEx/7ELQmF@@S9BjBYWNhbG@yOxnJnM5/l9vR/zJMd9nhNCxE32q5Bp18EYVP6YVIaloDpc42CYM8PgaOhgRS7IF1iGd9RlCZoR2TcuRUNtZRVwXRXFwW4NpdF/) Link includes faster test cases. Originally based on @Deadcode's answer to [Match strings whose length is a fourth power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19262/17602), but saved 7 bytes thanks to @Deadcode by improving the basic algorithm. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
^(?=(11+?)\1*$)
```

Start by matching the smallest factor `p` of `n`. (`p` is necessarily prime, of course.)

```
(?=(1+)(\3+$))
```

Find `n`s largest proper factor `m`, which is equivalent to `n` divided by its smallest prime factor `q` (which will be equal to `p` on the first pass).

```
\4
```

The factorisation also captures `n-m`, which is subtracted from the current value of `n`, effectively dividing `n` by `q` for the next pass of the loop.

```
(...)*\1$
```

Repeat this division by the smallest prime factor until `n` becomes `p`, which is only possible if `n` is a power of `p`.

Comment: -7 bytes while keeping the same algorithm. You only need to verify that `\1` is still the smallest prime factor at the end, not at each iteration of the loop: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDkIhEAX7dw5MdiEx/7ELQmF@@S9BjBYWNhbG@yOxnJnM5/l9vR/zJMd9nhNCxE32q5Bp18EYVP6YVIaloDpc42CYM8PgaOhgRS7IF1iGd9RlCZoR2TcuRUNtZRVwXRXFwW4NpdF/ "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")  BTW, in contrast with [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219939/17216), this one intrinsically doesn't treat 1 as a prime power – which [can actually be useful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259550/17216).

Comment: @Deadcode Strictly speaking it doesn't check that `p` is the smallest prime factor at the end, since the loop would otherwise be capable of iterating again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 238 bytes, 6 * 23 = 138 assembled bytes

```
main:li$v0,5
syscall
move$t3,$v0
li$a0,0
li$t2,2
w:bgt$t2,$t3,d
div$t3,$t2
mfhi$t0
bnez$t0,e
add$a0,$a0,1
s:div$t3,$t2
mfhi$t0
bnez$t0,e
div$t3,$t3,$t2
b s
e:add$t2,$t2,1
b w
d:move$t0,$a0
li$a0,0
bne$t0,1,p
add$a0,$a0,1
p:li$v0,1
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BDsIgDIbvfYodduwBUKPyNiCoJDBJIFv05bFlusSLh6bN369/25JDai2ZMOkYxlngAcqzXEyMkB6zH@sOSQXqGYE9V4UKFm1vlUsGHLgwd7IqSNc7MQLs5F@U0YNxjoc5JBT9l92aK2CHAl6zQV@lyMAOCzi93tZNt9vIhSWJ@Xdl/nwmv5@1po7n016@AQ)

Comment: You can save bytes if you use $2 through $9, rather than named registers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

Are all prime factors equal?

```
ḋ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GObtv//w2NjQ0B)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode) 17.0](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

```apl
⍸2⌊/⊢∨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU07TkNBDOw5xVwAsV7bu@u0NNASLhAJ5TWRoEWIChShBxtBQUkDTToKhESdo/giDwem8Fjz0SyuVocX14vV5TBN3n@yP41HPr77w9b71zT4@tn7xse73Sf7@sU3r/Oz47jnJ6fzaRnuDdFslvzxnnz8GLx/3x4sd9sMhqDBQAVZkSs4QwwlVAIxE7IkCokYpalFxJoQlEmCiCpLJGuz9MeaW24G72@SWLmkut8poJgqUAEZN2ij@KpqSbB/7CtUs0n0fgE)

Uses a different approach from [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220062), but only works for Dyalog 17.X. Errors with a domain error on non-prime powers, and doesn't error on truthy inputs.

The train is decomposed as the following

```apl
┌─┬─────────────────┐
│⍸│┌─┬─────┬───────┐│
│ ││ │┌─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┐││
│ ││2││⌊│/│││⊢│∨│⍳│││
│ ││ │└─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┘││
│ │└─┴─────┴───────┘│
└─┴─────────────────┘
```

First a range from 1 to the right argument is created using `⍳`.

```apl
      (⍳) 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Then each value in this list is [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)ed `∨` with the right argument `⊢`.

```apl
      (⊢∨⍳) 10
1 2 1 2 5 2 1 2 1 10
```

Then the pairwise minimum is taken, with the pairs overlapping, so `2⌊/1 3 2` is equivalent to `(1⌊3)(3⌊2)`.

```apl
      (2⌊/⊢∨⍳) 10
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1
```

Monadic `⍸` in Dyalog 17.0 is a function that finds the indices of truthy values given a binary array, but this function of it is irrelevant for this solution. If the input is not a prime power, it will have at least one number greater than 1 when the above is performed (proof below). Otherwise if it is a prime power, the above will result in a list with only 1s. So applying `⍸` on a non-prime power will cause the function to error because its argument is not a binary array, whereas on a prime power it won't error because the argument would binary consisting only of 1s.

In Dyalog 18.0 `⍸` has been extended to also accept non-binary arrays, so the above won't work. Instead, using 'unique' `∪` in place of `⍸` will return the 1-length vector consisting only of 1 for truthy values, and a longer vector for falsey values.

[Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410) gave the following proof as to why `2⌊/⊢∨⍳` does not give a vector of 1s for falsey values.

Consider the Diophantine equation \$p_1a-p_2b=1\$, where \$p_1\$ and \$p_2\$ are distinct prime factors of a non-prime tower \$N\$ and \$a,b>0\$. This equation has solutions, a proof of which can be found in the following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). What this equation means is that you will have a situation where a multiple of \$p_1\$ occurs as the number immediately following a multiple of \$p_2\$. Since each prime factor divides the input \$N\$, their multiple, when GCDed with the input, will result in a value greater than 1. The fact that these multiples are less than \$N\$ is left as an exercise to the reader. So the two multiples of prime numbers following one another and that these multiples are less than \$N\$ mean that you have a situation where `2⌊/⊢∨⍳` will have a number greater than 1 in it.

This situation does not occur for prime powers because given any two prime factors \$p^m\$ and \$p^n\$ where \$n>m\$, there will never be a situation where \$p^na-p^mb=1\$ because that would imply \$p(p^{n-1}a-p^{m-1}b)=1\$, i.e. that \$p\$ divides 1 which is false.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒g¶mÉk╒#─╧
```

Port of [*@Razetime*'s APL (Dyalog Classic) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210173/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1Enph7blHu7MBrKUH01peDR1@f//RlzGXCZcFlyWXIZmXEamXEbmXMZGXCaWXGZAUUMuMy5DoAozLlMTAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒           # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer)
 g          # Filter it by:
  ¶         #  Check if it's a prime
   m        # Map each prime to,
    É       # using the following three operations:
     k╒     #  Push a list in the range [1, input-integer) again
       #    #  Take the current prime to the power of each value in this list
        ─   # After the map, flatten the list of lists
         ╧  # And check if this list contains the (implicit) input-integer
            # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I feel like this should be 1 or 2 bytes shorter ...

```
k ä¶ ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ayDktiDX&input=WzIKMwo0CjgKOQoxNgoyNQoyNwozMgo0OQo2NAo4MQoxMzMxCjI0MDEKNDkxMwo2ODU5CjI3OTg0MQo1MzE0NDEKMTE3MzQ4MQo3ODkwNDgxCjQwMzUzNjA3Cjc1MjgyODkKNgoxMgozNgo1NAoxOTM4CjU4MTQKMTc1NTYwCjk5OTk5OTkKMTcyOTQ0MDMKXS1t) - includes all test cases

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ÆfE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xDQIxDEV7z@Iiju3EGQAxBKKE4nQLXEsByzAC3YlFWCR8Q6TE1vv5/l4u67rNud@vh/l@7Y/P7Xmc80SVSZmMKZgGkzSm6rgdHJqBtVQFmireakWSC2wtfOTfEQbmKpZVpKuloccov8aKuraCmd1r1ICJECQZjuoIkKHYwEOy7@6tYJ//SVCHYQjT@Qs)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
∨/1~⍨⊢∨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHSv0Dese9a541LUIyH7Uu/n/f/WQotKSjEorda40BSMgNgZiEyC2AGJLIDY0A0mYgghzkDRIjQlIwgysyhCkxNjYkItL3S0xpxhiDkiLIdgwEMsUpNDQ0hhkoqmFoQkA)

Outputs 1 if it isn't almost-prime, some other positive integer otherwise.

```apl
∨/1~⍨⊢∨⍳
     ⊢∨⍳   ⍝ All divisors
  1~⍨     ⍝ Remove 1
∨/         ⍝ GCD
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 4 bytes

```
ϼŁ1=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f///J6jjYa2//8bAgA)

```
ϼ         Implicit input; get unique ϼrime factors
 Ł        Łength of array
  1=      equals 1?; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>18 16 13</s> 11 bytes

*Thanks to [The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu) for -7 bytes*

```
ƛ?$Ḋ$æ∧;∑1=
```

[Run it](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGmz8k4biKJMOm4oinO+KIkTE9IiwiIiwiMjUiXQ==)

Explanation:

```
ƛ      ;    # map over the input with this code:
 ?          # get input
  $         # swap
   Ḋ        # divisible?
    $       # swap
     æ      # is the item prime?
      ∧     # logical and

        ∑   # sum
         1= # is 1?
```

Comment: Might help to use the register (`£`/`¥`) rather than named variables (`←x`)

Comment: Also, the range and duplicates are implicit: [Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCo8abwqUkJcKsJMOm4oinO+KIkTE9IiwiIiwiMjUiXQ==) or [verify more test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCInIiwiwqPGm8KlJCXCrCTDpuKIpzviiJExPSIsIiIsIjEwMCJd)

Comment: @TheThonnu How does Vyxal know that those operations are implicit?

Comment: When you loop over a number, it implicitly casts to a range. Also, when there is nothing left on the stack, the loop variable is used of you're in a loop, and the input is used otherwise.

Comment: Also, [11 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGmz8k4biKJMOm4oinO+KIkTE9IiwiIiwiMjUiXQ==). You can use `?` for the input rather than the register, and there is a command for "is divisible" rather than mod and not.

Comment: Ok, enough golfing.

Comment: [6 bytes :P](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ+w6bhuIriiJExPSIsIiIsIjI1Il0=) - filter for primes beforehand (`~`) then  no need for a map.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef), 19 bytes

```
f={.is_prime_power}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7dCsIwDIXvfYpeKpTRNEl/LnwSkTFwg8HU4S5kiM8@T2ahTfhOc3KW8dYP2zacP824tPNrvPft/Hz3r@@2dKu7RO/YO/GueFe9o@RdVNwMDk3AkqkEjRlvlEDGCWOpaLW/tQiYMolVosxiA7nUsDcSWDkFeGaNJZZ6bbppOg6nw54BO8lyoCp2UWWE0ULWZ9UUEO1/DMQq8IPDY4XD9gM)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! Nice language (although so far all I know about it is that it has primality-checking built-in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 6 bytes

```
rifCsm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KDPNuTj3/38TA2NTYzMDcwA)

Explanation:

```
ri      # Read integer from input
  fC    # Find its prime factorisation
    sm  # Are all values the same?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 25 bytes

```sh
>`factor`
dir <->|grep \
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7LCsJADLz3K@Yg0griZpPsA0r9EQ@KWi34Yn0cxH@vEXPITIaZJO/7cezrpq7Hbt1vto9rWVe7oaCdd59D2d@wwthMu8Vu/1pcnqdT27aTofr15QrGyhmzpuqvBQNqD4YgIYMCvMJHsIdkBFMJxEzw4sgkYoSk2Sw5CUGZxIAospgzpux@KI6Vg4uI6pNPtghkRwJUQJkTNJGxqBoc8r9s9FksaW@NXw)

Outputs via exit code - `1` is a prime power, `0` isn't.

- `factor` - factorise the input
- ``` >`` ``` - create a file named each word in that output (effectively uniquifies)
- `<->` - match any file that is just a number (eliminates the file called `input:` which comes from the output of `factor`)
- `dir` - list those files separated by spaces (as opposed to `ls` which separates by newlines)
- `|grep \`  - search for a space in that output (which means there were at least 2 matching files and therefore more than 1 distinct factor)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
fg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Lf3/fxMDY1NjMwNzAA)

```
fg  # full program
 g  # number of...
f   # prime factors of...
    # implicit input
    # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
†
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oCgIiwiIiwiMlxuM1xuNFxuOFxuOVxuMTZcbjI1XG4yN1xuMzJcbjQ5XG42NFxuODFcbjEzMzFcbjI0MDFcbjQ5MTNcbjY4NTlcbjI3OTg0MVxuNTMxNDQxXG4xMTczNDgxXG43ODkwNDgxXG40MDM1MzYwN1xuNzUyODI4OVxuNlxuMTJcbjM2XG41NFxuMTkzOFxuNTgxNFxuMTc1NTYwXG45OTk5OTk5XG4xNzI5NDQwMyJd)

Truthy outputs are `1`, falsy outputs are anything else.

## Explanation

```
† # length of prime factors
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
†ċ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oCgxIsiLCIiLCIyXG4zXG40XG44XG45XG4xNlxuMjVcbjI3XG4zMlxuNDlcbjY0XG44MVxuMTMzMVxuMjQwMVxuNDkxM1xuNjg1OVxuMjc5ODQxXG41MzE0NDFcbjExNzM0ODFcbjc4OTA0ODFcbjQwMzUzNjA3XG43NTI4Mjg5XG42XG4xMlxuMzZcbjU0XG4xOTM4XG41ODE0XG4xNzU1NjBcbjk5OTk5OTlcbjE3Mjk0NDAzIl0=)

Version with distinct and consistent (albeit inverted) truthy and falsy  values. A simple logical NOT `¬` could fix it for a fully correct 3 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oCgxIvCrCIsIiIsIjJcbjNcbjRcbjhcbjlcbjE2XG4yNVxuMjdcbjMyXG40OVxuNjRcbjgxXG4xMzMxXG4yNDAxXG40OTEzXG42ODU5XG4yNzk4NDFcbjUzMTQ0MVxuMTE3MzQ4MVxuNzg5MDQ4MVxuNDAzNTM2MDdcbjc1MjgyODlcbjZcbjEyXG4zNlxuNTRcbjE5MzhcbjU4MTRcbjE3NTU2MFxuOTk5OTk5OVxuMTcyOTQ0MDMiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 30 bytes

```
$=>[p:factors.prime&[]=p--p\0]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?fYb3Hp)

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 5 bytes

```
ffgen
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JU9LagMxDL2KyWoGXsCyJFtepBcpJWQxDgNhMEO66FmyGSihx-g5epsqjBC8D08Sevz0yzqfr337buH0_Ly3oz1bu07Lzv9-L73fvoYlHN9CX-fl7vTwEocwt2ldhzYsI8LkPTq-JzAEhgrKSIpUwAlSkd0lEDMhSSS3iJFNq0eqCUGZxIGosHiyWI0vlMjKORYUTZbMF4H8SIYKqLJBjZwV1RxR93KZqvjkx7i_sW07_gM)

A port of [@Sisyphus's Sagemath answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210170/9288).

Outputs via [exception](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/48931).

`ffgen(k)` returns a generator for the finite field of order \$k\$. It errors if \$k\$ is not a prime power.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 12 bytes

```
isprimepower
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JU5LagMxDL2KySoDL2BZki0vkouUUrLIhIFkYiYJpWfJZqCUbrrqbXqbKow276Onz-O77afh7djmzz5sv-63fmM_w7VNw_nQLu-HabH-fvetnT7WY9jsgjfHm9PVU6xCvx67DuElgSEwVFBGUqQCTpCK7C6BmAlJIrlFjGxaPVJNCMokDkSFxZPFanyiRFbOsaBosmS-CORHMlRAlQ1q5Kyo5oi6lMtUxSdfu-XzeV7wHw)

A boring built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 23 bytes

`{1;[1+;;%);[';/';;%!)<}`

takes input from stack, returns `1` if number is prime power and `0` otherwise

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=ezE7WzErOzslKTtbJzsvJzs7JSEpPH0KCjIgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4gXCBjYWxsIHByb2NlZHVyZSBhbmQgcHJpbnQgcmVzdWx0IGZvbGxvd2VkIGJ5IG5ldy1saW5lCjkgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KMTYgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KMjUgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KNDAzNTM2MDcgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KCjYgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KMTIgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KMzYgOz80OCsjLjEwIy4KMTc1NTYwIDs_NDgrIy4xMCMu)

## Explanation

Checks if the number has any prime factors that are larger than its smallest prime factor larger than 1.

```
 {                     }  \ anonymous procedure
  1;[1+;;%)               \ compute smallest non-trivial prime factor
  1                       \ push 1
   ;[1+;;%)               \ increase counter while it does not divide input number
           ;[';/';;%!)    \ divide number by smallest prime factor until it is no longer a factor
                      <   \ check if resulting number is less than the prime factor
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, <s>32</s> 25 bytes

Gets the prime factorization of the input and checks if it does *not* have a second element (effectively checking if the length is 1, since `n>=2` guarantees the length won't be 0).

```ruby
->n{!n.prime_division[1]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JU5LTsNADN2_U4S0CzapxuP5LspFQhSpagIjQVrlU4SqXoELsEGiXfUEHKW3wRBvnv0-tj_P_bR5v5Z50e_79Nrk1Xe7frxMY1uEn-KhO951q3-h3qZDGtKuK6k6zfrt_u05vTTZUzMOyPbTOGT54tiWy3o17upUnbLFss7RdNvZ_3X70GAYBESQg7bQHqxhIpywBGImaKNIKGK4YKNYYjAEy2QEiDwbcfoQ1R8axZad8vBWBx1kEUiOOFgDihxgA0nnrXUKcS4ZdTSSnN_6BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
fạ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWYlRTElQkElQTEmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0yJTBBMyUwQTQlMEE4JTBBOSUwQTE2JTBBMjUlMEEyNyUwQTMyJTBBNDklMEE2NCUwQTgxJTBBNiUwQTEyJTBBMzYlMEE1NCZmbGFncz1WZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
fạ  # Implicit input
f   # Prime factors
 ạ  # All equal
    # Implicit output
```