# The all-high powerful numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, primes

We've had [powerful numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/263438/66833), yes, but what about [*highly* powerful numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_powerful_number)?

#### Highly powerful numbers

Let \$n\$ be a positive integer in the form

$$n = p_1^{e_{p_1}(n)}p_2^{e_{p_2}(n)}\cdots p_k^{e_{p_k}(n)}$$

for distinct, increasing primes \$p_1, p_2, ..., p_k\$ and, where \$e_{p_i}(n)\$ is a positive integer for all \$i = 1, 2, ..., k\$. Note that we don't include zero exponents here.

Now, for such an \$n\$, define

$$\operatorname{prodexp}(n) = \begin{cases}
1, & n = 1 \\
\prod^k_{i=1} e_{p_i}(n), & n > 1\end{cases}$$

Such an \$n\$ is said to be *highly powerful* if, for all \$1 \le m < n\$, \$\operatorname{prodexp}(m) < \operatorname{prodexp}(n)\$.

For example, \$n = 8\$ is a highly powerful number as we have \$\operatorname{prodexp}(n) = 3\$ and

| \$m\$ | \$\operatorname{prodexp}(m)\$ |
| --- | --- |
| \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| \$2\$ | \$1\$ |
| \$3\$ | \$1\$ |
| \$4\$ | \$2\$ |
| \$5\$ | \$1\$ |
| \$6\$ | \$1\$ |
| \$7\$ | \$1\$ |

All of which are strictly less than \$3 = \operatorname{prodexp}(8)\$. Whereas \$n = 7\$ is not highly powerful as \$\operatorname{prodexp}(7) = 1 < 2 = \operatorname{prodexp}(4)\$.

The first few highly powerful numbers are

```
1, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 144, 216, 288, 432, 864, 1296, 1728, 2592
```

This is [A005934](https://oeis.org/A005934) on OEIS.

---

This is a standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge. You may choose whether to

- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the \$n\$th highly powerful number (you may choose between 0 and 1 indexing)
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ highly powerful numbers
- Output all highly powerful numbers indefinitely

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest answer in bytes in each language wins.

Comment: I have a 13 byte Jelly answer that outputs the first \$n\$. Brownie points for beating or tying this

Comment: So in plain(er) English, \$\operatorname{prodexp}(n)\$ is the product of the nonzero exponents in the prime decomposition of \$n\$, correct?

Comment: @DLosc Correct, yes

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
1ÆEP$ÐṀḢ=Ɗ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcJtrgMrhCQ93Njzcscj2WJcyUMwQAA)
Prints the first n numbers. -1 thanks to Jonathan Allan.

Brownie points acquired.

```
1           # Starting from 1
          # # Find the first n integers where...
 --------Ɗ  # Last three elements as a monad
        =   # Where the number equals
       Ḣ    # The first of
     ÐṀ     # The indicies of maximal elements by...
 ---$       # Last two elements as a monad...
   P        # Product of 
 ÆE         # Exponents of prime factorisation of the number.
```

Comment: `ÆEP$` [saves one byte](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcJtrgMrhCQ93Njzcscj2WJcyUMwQAA). This can be done since all-high-powerful-numbers have distinct prime factors that are a prefix of the primes. Proof by contradiction: assume there exists an all-high-powerful-number \$H=2^a 3^b 5^c \cdots p^0 (p+1)^n \cdots\$, this has an exponent-product of \$a b c \cdots n \cdots\$. The number \$C=2^a 3^b 5^c \cdots p^n \cdots\$ also has an exponent-product of \$a b c \cdots n \cdots\$ but \$C<H\$.

Comment: \* \$(p+1)\$ is meant to be the next prime after \$p\$ and \$a,b,c,n>0\$ if that is not clear.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Neat! That can save a byte or two on the 05AB1E answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ɾ‡∆ǐΠ∴=)ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuKAoeKIhseQzqDiiLQ9KcivIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) Outputs the first n highly powerful integers. -1 thanks to lyxal.

```
        ȯ # First n positive integers
-------)  # Where...
     ∴    # Maximum of...
ɾ         # Range from 1 to n
 ‡---     # By...
    Π     # Product of
  ∆ǐ      # Prime exponents
      =   # Is equal to the number?
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI1UiIsIiIsIsOe4oieJ+KAoeKIhseQzqDiiLQ9IiwiIiwiIl0=) for 9 bytes with the `R` flag

Comment: @lyxal I know, I just didn't want to use it

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuKAoeKIhseQzqDiiLQ9KcivIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) for 9 bytes without a flag

Comment: @lyxal Nice, I forgot `ȯ` can do that

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒDLÓPZk-
```

Outputs the infinite sequence.

-3 bytes thanks to *@JonathanAllan*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5NcfA5PDojK1v3/HwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞          # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ         # Filter it by:
  D        #  Duplicate the current value
   L       #  Pop one, and push a list in the range [1,value]
    Ó      #  Get the exponents of each inner integer's prime factorizations
           #  (which will include 0s, but this doesn't matter for the results)
     P     #  Get the product of each inner list
      Z    #  Push the maximum (without popping the list)
       k   #  Pop the maximum and list, and push the first (0-based) index of this max
        -  #  Subtract this 0-based index from the duplicated current value
           #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
           # (after which the filtered infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: No need to remove zeros, see my comments under emanresu A's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263678/the-all-high-powerful-numbers#comment577074_263683)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh, thanks! I had tried replacing `0δK` with some other things, like `>` or `!` to deal with the zeroes, but I hadn't tried simply removing it completely . Thanks for -3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 60 bytes

```
p=n=0;while(1,if(p<q=vecprod(factor(n++)[,2]),p=q;print(n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN20KbPNsDazLMzJzUjUMdTLTNApsCm3LUpMLivJTNNISk0vyizTytLU1o3WMYjV1CmwLrQuKMvNKNPI0NTUhZkCNghkJAA)

Outputs all highly powerful numbers indefinitely.

---

### 57 bytes but would stack overflow

```
f(p,n)=f(if(p<q=vecprod(factor(n++)[,2]),print(n);q,p),n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNy3TNAp08jRt0zQygSybQtuy1OSCovwUjbTE5JL8Io08bW3NaB2jWE2dgqLMvBKNPE3rQp0CTaAWiAGL0zSgLJiRAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 9 bytes

```
Ňᵖ{Rƒᵐ∏Ɔ<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FpuOtj_cOq066Nikh1snPOroP9Zms6Q4Kbl4WW2ioVFIHUQRTDEA)

```
Ňᵖ{Rƒᵐ∏Ɔ<
Ň           Any natural number
 ᵖ{         Check that:
   R          Range from 1 to the number
    ƒ         Factor each number
     ᵐ        Map:
      ∏         Take the product of exponents
       Ɔ<     Check that the last result is the largest
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

Output all highly powerful numbers indefinitely, as suggested by **[@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)**.

```javascript
for(x=p=0n;;p<s&&(p=s,console.log(x)))for(d=s=++x;d;)x%d+d--**x%x&&--s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpRCoAgDADQ0yQuW/RvO4w0iyKcuIjd3uh9vyu9Sbd21geLcO59l@aNKi0lxrqqc76STpsUlTvPtxzeAOBfTEohWOQINnBgxHG0wZxD1N4/)

### [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

Takes a positive integer \$ n \$ and returns the \$ n \$-th highly powerful number (1-indexed).

```javascript
n=>eval('for(x=p=0n;n;p<s&&(p=s,n--))for(d=s=++x;d;x%d+d--**x%x&&--s)x')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMgEADvfYWHxLixlvRstm@JRC0tskoMQQh5u7WnGZj5msPkdfukXVG0rnqshC93mCAGHzdRMOFEmnSaM@ciYb6TUgD/ZjGjlEVbXXorrVLjWPrCuVIZygC1PUwEtzNiyJ66YW6cmkgJN8bWSDkG9wjxLRYjupMuaGd3ekFwLaDrDw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 60 bytes

```
ＮθＷ‹Ｌυθ«→≔ⅈη≔¹ζ≔¹εＷ⊖η«≦⊕ε≔⌕⮌Ｘ⁰↨ηε⁰δ≧÷Ｘεδη¿δ≧×δζ»¿⬤υ›ζκ⊞υζ»Ｉⅈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBTsMwEETPyVfscS0ZKb3SU6EqqkRRVHHgapIltkic1nZSqajfHtapqYCDLc36zXjsSitX9aqdpq09DOFl6N7J4VEs85M2LQE@k/e82SZoHISEoxDwlWe7fiS835tGB2azlfemsfiGTOhfg4WE819JUabsNVWOOrKBatTX3GynDgne2ttpsv3EbIytcU8jOU9Y9iduXEh4UKx0RAW3KHjVs@mWOLfl2LA2o6lJwtVKEUy1M/MBWAv453k1HXnG0msu@cyt2hYHCU@OVOCcs4RPvhrKwes4j@glL52xAR@VD/F3hFhO06KY7sb2Gw) Link is to verbose version of code. Eventually outputs the 1-indexed `n`th highly powerful number (avoid `n>15` on TIO). Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｗ‹Ｌυθ«
```

Repeat until `n` record prime factorisation exponent product records have been found.

```
→≔ⅈη≔¹ζ≔¹ε
```

Increment the trial number and start to factorise it.

```
Ｗ⊖η«
```

Repeat until the trial number has been factorised.

```
≦⊕ε
```

Try the next potential factor.

```
≔⌕⮌Ｘ⁰↨ηε⁰δ
```

Find its multiplicity.

```
≧÷Ｘεδη
```

Divide the trial number by the prime power.

```
¿δ≧×δζ
```

Multiply the exponent product by the current exponent, if any.

```
»¿⬤υ›ζκ⊞υζ
```

If this is a record exponent product then save it.

```
»Ｉⅈ
```

Output the number with the `n`th record exponent product.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sadly I test all potential factors, not just primes, so for instance for 30 I divide by 2, 3, 4 and 5. The division by 4 fails of course, but I can't record that as a zero, since 4 isn't prime.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 234 bytes

```py
R=range
def P(n):
 d=[]
 while n>1:
  for i in R(2,n+1):
   if(i<3or all(i%j for j in R(2,i)))and 0==n%i:n//=i;d+=[i]
 r=1
 for i in{*d}:r*=d.count(i)
 return r
def f():
 n=0
 while(n:=n+1):
  if all(P(m)<P(n)for m in R(1,n)):print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9LDoJADED3nKIbkqkSAd2YkXoG45a4IA4jNVjIBGKM8ew4g59t@/L62j@GppPNtnfTdCRXyaWOTG3hoAR1BIbKUwT3htsaZJ/7CdjOAQMLHNU6kWUeMAC2iouNX1Vtqzi@ztj1hzEiVmIgI5KYtaQp8c4sqWRvd5RHf@tzYV7aLciszt0og2L0QD2MTsDNYVaFg0LZN0uJpl8F2/n8Qd2wCA8E6e3TkCeCqHvH3ik4ecv0Bg)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

Comment: while n>1 could be just while n

Comment: @BrianMinton Factorisation stops when `n=1`, not when `n=0`...

Comment: Although, `while~-n` would work, I think?

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
.fqh.M*FhMr8PZS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy@tMEPPV8stw7fIIiAq@P9/QwMA)

Outputs the first \$n\$ terms in the sequence.

#### Explanation

```
.fqh.M*FhMr8PZSZZQ    # implicitly add ZZQ
                      # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
.f               Q    # Take the first Q items which are truthy over lambda Z
              SZ      #   range(1,Z+1)
    .M                #   filter this for elements which maximize lambda Z
            PZ        #     prime factors of Z
          r8          #     length encode
        hM            #     take just the lengths
      *F              #     reduce over multiplication
   h                  #   first element
  q             Z     #   is equal to Z
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 17 bytes

```
⟨┅⟨ḋ_v2%Π⟩¦ṅ¤⌉>⟩#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9H8FY@mtALJhzu648uMVM8teDR/5aFlD3e2HlryqKfTDshT/v/f0AAA)

Returns the first (1-indexed) `n` all-high-powerful numbers.

There's a quirk with numeric mode `ḋ` where it returns a list `[prime,exponent]` for `n<4` and for `n>3` it returns a list `[[prime1,exponent1],...]`. I suppose that's what I get for golfing in a language that hasn't been updated in 6 years.

```
			; implicit input, n
⟨	       ⟩#	; find the first n positive integers where the following is truthy:
	   ṅ¤⌉>		; is the last element of the following list the unique maximum?
				; (literally, is the last element greater than the max of the remaining elements)
   ḋ_v2%Π  		; the product of the exponents in the prime factorization
 ┅⟨	 ⟩¦		; for each integer in the range 1..i (where i is the positive integer we're on now)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 75 bytes

Prints infinitely.

```ruby
p m=e=1
2.step{|x|d=x.prime_division.reduce(1){_1*_2[1]};m,e=p(x),d if d>e}
```

[Attempt This Online! (50ms timeout)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7E3totTC0syiVAX1EqBAfmmJOlcIhGFlBRXRMNAzMNVUSMlfWlqSpmtx07tAIdc21daQy0ivuCS1oLqmoibFtkIPbGJ8SmZZZnFmfp5eUWpKaXKqhqFmdbyhVrxRtGFsrXWuTqptgUaFpk6KQmaaQopdai3EyMWpeSkQ1oIFEBoA)

```ruby
# -rprime imports Prime as a command line flag
p m=e=1                 # Print 1 while also setting m (current most powerful)
                        #   and e (current highest exponent product)
2.step{|x|              # Count up infinitely starting from 2, store as x
  x.prime_division      # Get prime factors of x
   .reduce(1){_1*_2[1]} # Multiply the exponent component of each factor together
d=                      # Set that value as d
m,e=p(x),d if d>e       # if d > e, print x, set m to x, and set e to d
}                       # End loop structure
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 72 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG9CoAgEADgB1LoZ1XBKRAaGoIGcTjiSiEvtXt/@74MHDEDpxN6L4bMqI6YHvSTniUJoarZU8bP2hU@HuwCJ7/NEeONzVNQ7vJFV1lMVVtLxJZC6P0H)

```mathematica
p=n=0;While[1<2,n++;q=Times@@Last/@FactorInteger[n];If[p<q,p=q;Print@n]]
```